# Remove all files in a directory

Tags: python, unix, file-management

Trying to remove all of the files in a certain directory gives me the follwing error:

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/me/test/*'

The code I'm running is:

```
import os
test = "/home/me/test/*"
os.remove(test)
```

Comment: official document of os.walk does have a demo :) http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete the contents of a folder in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185936/how-to-delete-the-contents-of-a-folder-in-python)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`os.remove()` does not work on a directory, and `os.rmdir()` will only work on an empty directory. And Python won't automatically expand "/home/me/test/*" like some shells do.

You can use `shutil.rmtree()` on the directory to do this, however.

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('/home/me/test')
```

be careful as it removes the files *and the sub-directories* as well.

Comment: import shutil; shutil.rmtree('/home/me/test')

Comment: Note that using shutil.rmtree() will also delete the folder on the end of the path given (it doesn't delete directory contents it deletes the directory)

Comment: that doesn't explain why `/home/me/test/*` isn't accepted by `os.remove`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: This answer is not correct since it does not keep the emptied directory.

Answer (score 24):

os.remove doesn't resolve unix-style patterns. If you are on a unix-like system you can:

```
os.system('rm '+test)
```

Else you can:

```
import glob, os
test = '/path/*'
r = glob.glob(test)
for i in r:
   os.remove(i)
```

Comment: os.system has many caveats, including not resolving glob patterns either (as it just passes the line to the shell); glob returns directories as well as files (which os.remove doesn't handle)

Comment: the best answer so far:

Answer (score 18):

Bit of a hack but if you would like to keep the directory, the following can be used.

```
import os
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('/home/me/test') 
os.mkdir('/home/me/test')
```

Answer (score 7):

Because the * is a shell construct.  Python is literally looking for a file named "*" in the directory /home/me/test.  Use listdir to get a list of the files first and then call remove on each one.

Answer (score 5):

Although this is an old question, I think none has already answered using this approach:

```
# python 2.7
import os

d='/home/me/test'
filesToRemove = [os.path.join(d,f) for f in os.listdir(d)]
for f in filesToRemove:
    os.remove(f)
```

Comment: You need to include the full path to the file when you use `os.remove()`, so you'd have to do `os.remove(os.path.join("/home/me/test", f))` for this to work.

Comment: plus the line `os.remove(f) for f in files` is not valid syntax. Not everything uses comprehension.

Comment: I quite like this answer, using `os` calls. I've used it as the basis of my work: `filesToRemove = [f for f in os.listdir(self.my_folder)]
for f in filesToRemove:
    os.remove(os.path.join(self.my_folder, f))` (indentation required).

Comment: what if I want to use relative path? please help

Comment: @deef - I re-factored to include that requirement.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - re-factored to use standard python iteration.

Answer (score 4):

This will get all files in a directory and remove them.

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "foldername")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
  for file in files:
    path = os.path.join(dir, file)
    os.remove(path)
```

Answer (score 3):

star is expanded by Unix shell. Your call is not accessing shell, it's merely trying to remove a file with the name ending with the star

Answer (score 1):

shutil.rmtree() for most cases. But it doesn't work for in Windows for readonly files. For windows import win32api and win32con modules from PyWin32.

```
def rmtree(dirname):
    retry = True
    while retry:
        retry = False
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(dirname)
        except exceptions.WindowsError, e:
            if e.winerror == 5: # No write permission
                win32api.SetFileAttributes(dirname, win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL)
                retry = True
```

Answer (score 0):

os.remove will only remove a single file.

In order to remove with wildcards, you'll need to write your own routine that handles this.

There are [quite a few suggested approaches](http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/deleting-files-with-python-108565.html) listed on this forum page.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24844618/2293304

It's a long and ugly, but reliable and efficient solution.

It resolves a few problems which are not addressed by the other answerers:

- It correctly handles symbolic links, including not calling `shutil.rmtree()` on a symbolic link (which will pass the `os.path.isdir()` test if it links to a directory).
- It handles read-only files nicely.

Comment: in that case, the best way is to flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
#python 2.7
import tempfile
import shutil
import exceptions
import os

def TempCleaner():
    temp_dir_name = tempfile.gettempdir()
    for currentdir in os.listdir(temp_dir_name):
        try:
           shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(temp_dir_name, currentdir))
        except exceptions.WindowsError, e:
            print u'Не удалось удалить:'+ e.filename
```

Answer (score 0):

To Removing all the files in folder.

```
import os
import glob

files = glob.glob(os.path.join('path/to/folder/*'))
files = glob.glob(os.path.join('path/to/folder/*.csv')) // It will give all csv files in folder
for file in files:
    os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way I've done this:

```
os.popen('rm -f ./yourdir')
```

Comment: not portable and `rm -f directory` just doesn't work. I wonder why this is upvoted that much.