# How do I convert all of the items in a list to floats?

Tags: python, list, casting

I have a script which reads a text file, pulls decimal numbers out of it as strings and places them into a list.

So I have this list:

```
my_list = ['0.49', '0.54', '0.54', '0.55', '0.55', '0.54', '0.55', '0.55', '0.54']
```

How do I convert each of the values in the list from a string to a float?

I have tried:

```
for item in my_list:
    float(item)
```

But this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Don't use list as a variable name.

Comment: To elaborate on above comment: using `list` as a variable name will shadow the built-in `list` constructor thus not allowing you to use  that in the same scope

Answer (score 623, accepted):

```
[float(i) for i in lst]
```

to be precise, it creates a new list with float values. Unlike the `map` approach it will work in py3k.

Comment: For large array's, I would recommend using numpy:  `np.array(inp_list, dtype=np.float32)`. You don't even have to specify if it's a float and just use: `np.array(inp_list)`

Comment: @Thomas Devoogdt : I think you do need to specify the type, otherwise you will get a numpy array of strings

Comment: Please note that you have to assign `[float(i) for i in lst]` to something. E.g.: `new_list = [float(i) for i in lst]`

Comment: Why doesn't python have a professional function to perform this operation?

Comment: Depending on your security expectations, you might as well just "eval" like  `eval(my_list.join(", "))`

Answer (score 164):

`map(float, mylist)` should do it.

(In Python 3, map ceases to return a list object, so if you want a new list and not just something to iterate over, you either need `list(map(float, mylist)` - or use SilentGhost's answer which arguably is more pythonic.)

Comment: This is in fact a design sub-optimality in Python 3.

Answer (score 37):

This would be an other method (without using any loop!):

```
import numpy as np
list(np.float_(list_name))
```

Comment: Don't need to cast the np.array into the list again if you like to keep it as an np.array =)

Answer (score 17):

`float(item)` do the right thing: it converts its argument to float and and return it, but it doesn't change argument in-place. A simple fix for your code is:

```
new_list = []
for item in list:
    new_list.append(float(item))
```

The same code can written shorter using list comprehension: `new_list = [float(i) for i in list]`

To change list in-place:

```
for index, item in enumerate(list):
    list[index] = float(item)
```

BTW, avoid using `list` for your variables, since it masquerades built-in function with the same name.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get what in-place means here. How does it differ from the previous pythonic answer. Doesn't the conversion in the previous answer "[float(i) for i in lst]" retain the original list index

Comment: @AAI Change original list vs. create a new one.

Answer (score 16):

you can even do this by numpy

```
import numpy as np
np.array(your_list,dtype=float)
```

this return np array of your list as float

you also can set 'dtype' as int

Comment: But then you are returning a numpy array, not a list.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `map()` function to convert the list directly to `floats`:

```
float_list = map(float, list)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy to convert a list directly to a floating array or matrix.

```
    import numpy as np
    list_ex = [1, 0] # This a list
    list_int = np.array(list_ex) # This is a numpy integer array
```

If you want to convert the integer array to a floating array then add 0. to it

```
    list_float = np.array(list_ex) + 0. # This is a numpy floating array
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it.

```
my_list = ['0.49', '0.54', '0.54', '0.54', '0.54', '0.54', '0.55', '0.54', 
    '0.54', '0.54', '0.55', '0.55', '0.55', '0.54', '0.55', '0.55', '0.54', 
    '0.55', '0.55', '0.54']
print type(my_list[0]) # prints <type 'str'>
my_list = [float(i) for i in my_list]
print type(my_list[0]) # prints <type 'float'>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use numpy to avoid looping:

```
import numpy as np
list(np.array(my_list).astype(float)
```

Comment: Why would you use your approach rather than `import numpy as np
list(np.float_(list_name))` from the answer above?

Comment: There appears to be a missing closing parenthesis `)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
newlist = list(map(float, mylist))
```

Comment: Your answer is correct +1. From `python 3.5` you can also do `[*map(float, mylist)]` to the same effect. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/38702484/3957794

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
my_list = ['0.49', '0.54', '0.54', '0.54', '0.54', '0.54', '0.55', '0.54', '0.54', '0.54', '0.55', '0.55', '0.55', '0.54', '0.55', '0.55', '0.54', 
'0.55', '0.55', '0.54']
print(type(my_list), type(my_list[0]))   
# <class 'list'> <class 'str'>
```

which displays the type as a list of strings. You can convert this list to an array of floats simultaneously using numpy:

```
    my_list = np.array(my_list).astype(np.float)

    print(type(my_list), type(my_list[0]))  
    # <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to extract numbers first from a list of float strings:

```
   df4['sscore'] = df4['simscore'].str.findall('\d+\.\d+')
```

then each convert to a float:

```
   ad=[]
   for z in range(len(df4)):
      ad.append([float(i) for i in df4['sscore'][z]])
```

in the end assign all floats to a dataframe as float64:

```
   df4['fscore'] = np.array(ad,dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(list)): list[i]=float(list[i])
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solve this problem in my program using:

```
number_input = float("{:.1f}".format(float(input())))
list.append(number_input)
```

Comment: The OP states that he is reading from a text file. this answer does not apply to what has been asked.