# [float(i) for i in lst]

Tags: python, python-3.x

prorgamming newbie--I was looking for answers to an exercise I was doing and got my answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1614236/731819). My question is this--from that thread, the one chosen as best answer, was this code

```
[float(i) for i in lst]
```

The code did what it was supposed to do, but when I tried to get to that new list, I am getting errors

```
>>> xs = '12 10 32 3 66 17 42 99 20'.split()
>>> [float(i) for i in xs]
[12.0, 10.0, 32.0, 3.0, 66.0, 17.0, 42.0, 99.0, 20.0]
>>> i
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

How should I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Whenever the python prompt prints something out, it's because whatever you just typed returned a value.  You can keep that value by assigning a variable to the expression you typed, but then nothing will be printed out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to assign `[float(i) for i in xs]` to something:

```
>>> new_list = [float(i) for i in xs]
>>> new_list
[12.0, 10.0, 32.0, 3.0, 66.0, 17.0, 42.0, 99.0, 20.0]
>>> new_list[0]
12.0
>>> new_list[5]
17.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using map:

```
xs = '12 10 32 3 66 17 42 99 20'.split()
new_xs = map(float, xs)
```

Comment: Using [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) is certainly the neatest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike for loops that leave the last iteration bound to the variable the var inside a list comp stops existing after evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

`i` only exists inside the list comprehension.

You want to say:

```
i = [float(i) for i in lst]
```

Comment: Using `i` as a variable inside and outside of the list comprehension could lead to unnecessary confusion.

Comment: or rather, maybe what you really *want* to say is `floatlist = [....`, since naming the list after the iterator is a bit confusing.

Comment: for completeness, `i` only exists inside the list comprehension in Python 3. In Python 2, you can access `i` outside.

Answer (score 0):

This is something related to Python versions. Look:
On Python 2, if you do:

```
>>> i = 1234
>>> j = [i for i in xrange(10)]
>>> print i
9
```

But this was fixed in Python 3:

```
>>> i = 1234
>>> j = [i for i in range(10)]
>>> print(i)
1234
```

If you have Python 3.0 or superior, the variable will only be available in the comprehension. It will not affect the rest of the environment

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to assigning a name to your list comprehension, in Python interactive mode, the symbol `_` is automatically assigned to the last expression evaluated by the interpreter. So you could do the following:

```
>>> xs = '12 10 32 3 66 17 42 99 20'.split()
>>> [float(i) for i in xs]
[12.0, 10.0, 32.0, 3.0, 66.0, 17.0, 42.0, 99.0, 20.0]
>>> _
[12.0, 10.0, 32.0, 3.0, 66.0, 17.0, 42.0, 99.0, 20.0]
>>> _[2]
32.0
>>> _
32.0
```