# Python - Turn all items in a Dataframe to strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I followed the following procedure: [In Python, how do I convert all of the items in a list to floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614236/in-python-how-do-i-convert-all-of-the-items-in-a-list-to-floats) because each column of my Dataframe is `list`, but instead of `floats` I chose to change all the values to `strings`.

`df = [str(i) for i in df]`

But this failed.

It simply erased all the data except for the first row of column names.

Then, trying `df = [str(i) for i in df.values]` resulted in changing the entire Dataframe into one big list, but that messes up the data too much to be able to meet the goal of my script which is to export the Dataframe to my Oracle table.

Is there a way to convert all the items that are in my Dataframe that are NOT strings into strings?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use `applymap` method:

```
df = df.applymap(str)
```

Comment: That worked absolutely perfect and fixed my entire code. Thanks a ton

Comment: I don't know how big your dataframe is, but it seems astype is quite a lot faster. See my answer :).

Comment: Be careful using this with nan values, it will turn them into 'nan' strings.

Comment: Both `astype(str)` and `applymap(str)` leave column types as "object" causing problems later. How to convert into string for good?

Answer (score 106):

You can use this:

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

out of curiosity I decided to see if there is any difference in efficiency between the accepted solution and mine.

The results are below:

example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list(range(1000))], index=[0])
```

test `df.astype`:

```
%timeit df.astype(str) 
>> 100 loops, best of 3: 2.18 ms per loop
```

test `df.applymap`:

```
%timeit df.applymap(str)
1 loops, best of 3: 245 ms per loop
```

It seems `df.astype` is quite a lot faster :)

Comment: how would you do this if you wanted to convert a list of dataframes to string?

Comment: list_of_dfs = [df.astype(str) for df in list_of_dfs]

Comment: this seems to put all the dataframes into a list of dataframes and although it does convert them to strings it doesn't actually convert the original dfs into strings. I'd have to unpack them and reassign them to their original df names. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: this works [df_a, df_b, df_c] = [df.astype(str) for df in [df_a, df_b, df_c]], but this doesn't. list_of_dfs = [df.astype(str) for df in list_of_dfs]

Comment: Ah, didn't really get what you meant. glad you solved it!

Comment: [df.astype(str, copy=False) for df in list_of_dfs] will probably also work if I understand you correctly, but the documentation warns against using this.

Answer (score 9):

**With pandas >= 1.0 there is now a dedicated string datatype:**

You can convert your column to this pandas **string datatype** using [.astype('string')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html):

```
df = df.astype('string')
```

This is different from using `str` which sets the pandas 'object' datatype:

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

You can see the difference in datatypes when you look at the info of the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'zipcode_str': [90210, 90211] ,
    'zipcode_string': [90210, 90211],
})

df['zipcode_str'] = df['zipcode_str'].astype(str)
df['zipcode_string'] = df['zipcode_str'].astype('string')

df.info()

# you can see that the first column has dtype object
# while the second column has the new dtype string
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------          --------------  ----- 
 0   zipcode_str     2 non-null      object
 1   zipcode_string  2 non-null      string
dtypes: object(1), string(1)
```

From the docs:

> The 'string' extension type solves several issues with object-dtype
>   NumPy arrays:
>
> 1) You can accidentally store a mixture of strings and non-strings in an
>   object dtype array. A StringArray can only store strings.
>
> 2) object dtype breaks dtype-specific operations like
>   DataFrame.select_dtypes(). There isn’t a clear way to select just text
>   while excluding non-text, but still object-dtype columns.
>
> 3) When reading code, the contents of an object dtype array is less clear
>   than string.

Information about pandas 1.0 can be found here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html

Comment: This also handles NaN or NA values properly. Which is not the case for str.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
dt.applymap(lambda x: x[0] if type(x) is list else None)
```