# how to convert list type into float in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying convert `list` data type into `float`. I have tried following code but its not working, `listf` still showing data type as list

```
for x in range(0,5):
     timeVar.append((matchedLine4[x]).replace(stringToMatch4,'').rstrip())
     listf=map(float,timeVar)
     #list1 = [float(i) for i in timeVar]
     print(type(listf))
```

Comment: Please provide additional information about what you're trying to achieve as well as an example case to clarify your question. You should know that `list` is an `iterable` whereas `float` is not. That means that you cannot convert a `list` into `float`, you can convert any numeric elements of the list to `float`, but not the list itself.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614236/in-python-how-do-i-convert-all-of-the-items-in-a-list-to-floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot generally convert a list to a float.  But if you convert the string to a float first and then add to the list, it will be easier and could look like:

#### Code:

```
matchedLine4 = '1 2 3x 4 5.7'.split()
listf = []
stringToMatch4 = 'x'
for x in range(0, 5):
    timeVar = float(matchedLine4[x].replace(stringToMatch4, '').rstrip())
    listf.append(timeVar)
print(listf)
```

#### Results:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.7]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
listf = list(map(float, timeVar))
```