# long list that has many lists of longs

Tags: python

I have this variable of type long that is a list of longs:

```
print(list_id)
[6L]
[6L]
[6L]
[6L]
[7L]
```

How to convert this list to something like:

```
list_id = [6, 6, 6, 6, 7]
```

I did something like this:

```
list_orgs_id = []
for i in list_id[0]:
    list_orgs_id.append(i)
print(list_orgs_id)
```

but it says:

```
TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable
```

Comment: try `list_id  =list(map(int,list_id))`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1614236/2125723

Comment: @ryanwebjackson it's not the same thing. I have a nested list. ( list of lists)

Comment: The question you are refering is quite simple. My question is different!!

Comment: The list is returned by an SQLAlchemy query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast them to integers with `int()`.

```
list_id = [[6L], [6L], [6L], [6L], [7L]]
int_id = [int(i[0]) for i in list_id]
print(int_id)
```

Output:

```
[6, 6, 6, 6, 7]
```

Terminal output:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> list_id = [[6L], [6L], [6L], [6L], [7L]]
>>> int_id = [int(i[0]) for i in list_id]
>>> print(int_id)
[6, 6, 6, 6, 7]
>>>
```

Comment: the list you mentioned is not correct. This is the list : `list_id = [[6L], [6L], [6L], [6L], [7L]]`

Comment: I tried this and it gives this error: `TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable`

Comment: Sorry, small typo fixed again.

Comment: I tried your update and now i have: `TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: I just ran it in my terminal and works perfectly. Check that `list_id` is what you think it is.

Comment: We are not using the same version

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?Simply use `list comprehension`

```
main_list = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
list_id=[j for i in main_list for j in i]
print(list_id)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I tried `list_ids = [int(i) for i in list_id[0]]` and it says 'long' object is not iterable

Comment: Have you tried `list_ids = [int(i) for i in list_id[0].items()]` ?

Comment: Yes just did and it said: `AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'items'
`

Comment: Which version of Python you are using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: When I write `list_id = [[6L], [6L], [6L], [6L], [7L]]` it shows `Python version 3.6 does not support tailing l or L`. How have you recovered this error?

Comment: I get the list from SQLAlchemy query

Comment: @Somar `long` datatypes do not exist in python 3.x. The `int` itself is `long` & these don't have to be suffixed by `L`.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

You could apply `int()` to all the elements in the list of list:

```
for x in range(len(list_id)):
    list_id[x] = int(list_id[x][0])
```

### Method 2

You could also choose to write it in a fancy **list comprehension**:

```
list_id = [int(y) for x in list_id for y in x]
```

In this case you have to iterate over all the lists inside `list_id` and during each iteration you will iterate over the long integer inside those list. This is similar to:

```
temp = []

for x in list_id:
    for y in x:
        temp.append(int(x))

list_id = temp
```

### Method 3

You could, if you want, write a user defined function and apply that using `map()` function on all the elements of `list_id`:

```
def func(list):
    return int(list[0])

list_id = map(func, list_id)

list_id = list(map)
# This line is not required if you just want to iterate over the values.
```