# Converting list to be float instead of strings when reading from file

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I am loading data from a file and want it to be stored in a matrix. I am looking to read the data in as a float rather than a string. How do I do this?

```
with open("hw2_data.txt", "r") as dataFile: 
    X = [line.split() for line in dataFile]
```

I have tried various things with float() but cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1614247/6505847)

Comment: Please share what you’ve tried. Have you done any research? Also, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested listcomp or `map` to do this:

```
X = [[float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in dataFile]
```

or:

```
X = [[*map(float, line.split())] for line in dataFile]
```

`[*map(...)]` is just the unpacking way of spelling `list(map(...))`; you can use either on any supported version of Python 3.