# Cannot convert list of strings to list of floats in python using float()

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I am trying to change the elements of a list of strings to floats using the method defined in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614236/in-python-how-do-i-convert-all-of-the-items-in-a-list-to-floats). I write

```
with open('posx_mean_no_acoplo_tf_multiple.txt', 'r') as fmediaXoriginal:
    contentmediaXoriginal = fmediaXoriginal.readlines()
    contentmediaXoriginal = [x.strip() for x in contentmediaXoriginal] 
    [float(i) for i in contentmediaXoriginal]
```

As specified in the other thread. However, if I write `print(type(contentmediaXoriginal[2]))`, then, the output is `<class 'str'>`. As far as I can see, I am following the accepted answer to the letter. Can someone tell me why my code is not converting the elements of contentmediaXoriginal to floats?

The first 5 lines of posx_mean_no_acoplo_tf_multiple.txt are:

```
2.25
2.2695317544146922
2.329339980428795
2.4250625977456477
2.5550797011698574
```

Comment: What is the format of `posx_mean_no_acoplo_tf_multiple.txt` ?

Comment: Could you please post a few lines of `posx_mean_no_acoplo_tf_multiple.txt`?

Comment: It is a text file, an output from another python file.

Comment: Here is a link https://postimg.cc/hzrgqb2m

Comment: Please post the first 5 lines as part of the question, so that your problem is clearer.

Comment: I have posted the first five lines. The format is text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. You just have not assigned the output. Try this

```
with open('posx_mean_no_acoplo_tf_multiple.txt', 'r') as fmediaXoriginal:
contentmediaXoriginal = fmediaXoriginal.readlines()
contentmediaXoriginal = [float(x.strip()) for x in contentmediaXoriginal]
```

Note: Please fix indentation as you require it.