# How can I change multiple integers to floats?

Tags: python

```
x = (2, 3, 4)    

a, b, c = x
    
d, e, f = float(a, b, c)
    
print(d)
```

This gives an error.
Is it possible to change multiple integers to floats?

Comment: You don't have a list of integers anywhere in your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I convert all of the items in a list to floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1614236/2745495)

Comment: Documented here:
```
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float
````
Says that float() only takes a number or string
```
Return a floating point number constructed from a number or string x.
```

Comment: The variables a,b and c are integers, but they are not defined as a list. `list_ints = [2,3,4]` or `list_ints = [a,b,c]` would work. Converting that in a oneliner would be `list_ints = [float(x) for x in list_ints]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a, b, c = map(float, (a, b, c))
```