# How to convert list of strings into floats?

Tags: python

I have the list of data:

```
rfd_per_neihborhood_15 = ['75.8', '108.5', '76.6', '96.4', '104.8', '95.8', '165.8', '128.9']
```

I need to convert it into float in order to calculate the average and etc.

I've tried:

```
list(map(float, rfd_per_neihborhood_15))

list(np.float_(rfd_per_neihborhood_15))
```

```
for item in list:
    float(item)
```

```
a = rfd_per_neihborhood_15
floats = []
for element in a:
    floats.append(float(element))
print(floats)
```

Nothing is working, it's throwing `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I convert all of the items in a list to floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614236/in-python-how-do-i-convert-all-of-the-items-in-a-list-to-floats)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be that there is an element in your list which has a `-` (hyphen). To tackle that, you can use `try-except` in the following manner:

```
rfd_per_neihborhood_15 = ['75.8','108.5','76.6','96.4','104.8','95.8','165.8','128.9','4-4']

def safe_float(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        print(f"Cannot convert {x}")
        #Returning a 0 in case of an error. You can change this based on your usecase
        return 0
list(map(safe_float, rfd_per_neihborhood_15))
```

Output:

```
Cannot convert 4-4
[75.8, 108.5, 76.6, 96.4, 104.8, 95.8, 165.8, 128.9, 0]
```

As you can see, my code gracefully handled the exception and returned a `0` in place of the last element `'4-4'`. Alternatively, you could also return a `NaN`.

Comment: you were right, I thought that problem with the code, but I had one data with no value. Thank you very much, I will pay more attention to my data source before working with it

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
rfd_per_neihborhood_15 = ['75.8', '108.5', '76.6', '96.4', '104.8', '95.8', '165.8', '128.9']

# shortening the name to r_pn15
r_pn15 = rfd_per_neihborhood_15

floated_list = []
for item in r_pn15:
    r_pn15.append(float(item))

print(floated_list)
```