# How to plot using python(Matplotlib) two list in which one list contain year and second contain Negative and positive values

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have two lists -

```
years = ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020']
profits = ['362', '622', '-409', '-92', '-148', '-130', '-128', '98', '-74', '35', '-419']
```

How can I plot this list, and in which chart should I use here?

I tried this code but output is not right -

```
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# Figure Size
fig = plt.figure(figsize =(10, 7))
 
# Horizontal Bar Plot
plt.bar(years, profits)
 
# Show Plot
plt.show()
```

Wrong output which I'm getting:

[image: My Wrong Output Graph Image]

Comment: you're plotting strings.  Convert to int or float

Comment: Your question as stated does not use [tag:pandas] you have two python lists passed directly to matplotlib. If you are in some way using pandas objects like `Series` or `DataFrame.plot` please update your question to reflect these elements and re-add the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have a list of strings. You should convert it to a list of floats using

```py
years = list(map(float, years))
profits = list(map(float, profits))
```

If you want a list of ints, just change `float` to `int`.

Comment: Thanks it's woking, can you please tell me logic behind this.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1614249/9997212).

Comment: @KrishnaGupta, its equivalent of ```[float(i) for i in years]```