# Python error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'list'

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I am new to programming and taking online courses at the moment. I am stuck on this specific exercise:

I have a sample.txt that contains a bunch of text with numbers all throughout the text. My goal is to parse the lines for the numbers only and then find the sum.

Here is the sample.txt:

```
Why should you learn to write programs? 7746
12 1929 8827
Writing programs (or programming) is a very creative 
7 and rewarding activity.  You can write programs for 
many reasons, ranging from making your living to solving
8837 a difficult data analysis problem to having fun to helping 128
someone else solve a problem.  This book assumes that 
everyone needs to know how to program ...
```

Here is my code:

```
import re
name = input('Enter File: ')
if len(name) < 1 :
    name = 'sample.txt'
handle = open(name)
numlist = list()
for line in handle :
    line = line.rstrip()
    items = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    if len(items) > 0 :
        #print(items)
        num = float(items[0: ])
        numlist.append(num)
print(sum(numlist))
```

Comment: `items[0:]` is the same thing as `items`: a list of the numbers that your regex found, not any one of those numbers in particular.  You would need another `for` loop to go through `items` and call `float()` on each one individually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I convert all of the items in a list to floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614236/in-python-how-do-i-convert-all-of-the-items-in-a-list-to-floats)

Comment: Why `float` when all the given numbers are `int'? You may convert the numbers (which come out in `str` type) to `int` via a `for` loop and then simply sum the items in the list. Having said that, if you essentially need a `float` well, the logic is still the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert a list to a float.

```
num = float(items[0:])
# note, the [0:] is redundant, it will just return the whole list
```

You can either convert the whole list at once using map

```
nums = list(map(float, items))
```

Or you can convert them one at a time like this

```
nums = []
for item in items:
  nums.append(float(item))
```

I think the better way is to convert the whole list at once using the map function
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/