# Python sched alternative to cancel all events

Tags: python, events

I'm looking for an alternative to the sched module which would allow me to cancel all events at any time. sched only allows to cancel single events by id (which is returned from the scheduler when an event is scheduled).
Any pointers to Python alternatives to sched would be appreciated.
Thanks
Toni p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In python 2.6, there is a read-only attribute called `queue` returning a list of upcoming events. So this will cancel all events:

```
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
map(s.cancel, s.queue)
```

**Update for Python 3:**

Python 3 map() returns the iterator. Therefore, the object must be converted to the list.

```
s = sched.scheduler (time.time, time.sleep)
list(map(s.cancel, s.queue))
```

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/1303354/6523409 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/13623676/6523409

Comment: Works for Python 2.5 too. Sorry, should have mentioned my version.