# Python 3 Map function is not Calling up function

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, map-function

Why doesn't following code print anything:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
class test:
    def do_someting(self,value):
        print(value)
        return value

    def fun1(self):
        map(self.do_someting,range(10))

if __name__=="__main__":
    t = test()
    t.fun1()
```

I'm executing the above code in Python 3. I think i'm missing something very basic but not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[`map()` returns an iterator](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), and will not process elements until you ask it to.

Turn it into a list to force all elements to be processed:

```
list(map(self.do_someting,range(10)))
```

or use `collections.deque()` with the length set to 0 to not produce a list if you don't need the map output:

```
from collections import deque

deque(map(self.do_someting, range(10)))
```

but note that simply using a `for` loop is far more readable for any future maintainers of your code:

```
for i in range(10):
    self.do_someting(i)
```

Comment: Also, the OP may just be missing a `return`, but it's generally not considered good practice to use `map` to execute a function repeatedly for side-effects (in this case `print`) as opposed to working with the result set...

Comment: @JonClements: The OP is playing around with the map function and created a short piece of example code to show that things didn't work as he expected, I'd say.

Comment: Creating a temporary list is not the best thing, I'd say. The **`consume` [recipe](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)** may be better.

Comment: Note that creating a `collection.deque` with `maxlen=0` is equivalent to calling `itertools.consume`. The latter, however, is much more readable to me since it is clear that you want to consume the iterator.

Comment: @rugortal there is no `itertools.consume()`. There is a `consume()` example function definition in the [`itertools` documentation recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), but that’s not part of what the module provides.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you're right, thanks for pointing that out. I got confused because, while a recipe for `consume` indeed exists in `itertools`, they do not provide such function. Instead, one can find `consume` implemented in [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.consume).

Comment: `for` loops are better for smaller code blocks. i personally prefer a functional approach with `map` calls, and dividing code into smaller chunks when the instruction set gets large. i highly recommend this book on the subject: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/functional-programming-in/9781492048633/

Answer (score 10):

Before Python 3, map() returned a list, not an iterator.  So your example would work in Python 2.7.

list() creates a new list by iterating over its argument.  ( list() is NOT JUST a type conversion from say tuple to list.  So list(list((1,2))) returns [1,2]. )  So list(map(...)) is backwards compatible with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add the following:

`With multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted` [ https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map ]

Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)

```
>>> list(map(lambda a, b: [a, b], [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']))
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, None]]
```

Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11)

```
>>> list(map(lambda a, b: [a, b], [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']))
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]
```

That difference makes the answer about simple wrapping with `list(...)` not completely correct

The same could be achieved with:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [[a, b] for a, b in itertools.zip_longest([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'])]
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, None]]
```