# Map function or lambda does not work as expected in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

My code does not work as expected. My partial code looks like this:

```
lst_of_players = []

class Player:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        self.level = 1
        lst_of_players.append(self)

    def level_up(self):
        self.level += 1


player1 = Player("Player 1")
player2 = Player("Player 2")
player3 = Player("Player 3")

def level_up_all_players():
    map(lambda player: player.level_up(), lst_of_players)
```

I thought the players' levels would be leveled up by 1 when i call level_up_all_players func, but it does not.
When I print the levels of players, they still had the levels they had before calling the function.

Comment: You should also add each player to your `lst_of_players`; as it stands your minimal example won't work because nothing is in the list. I assume this is a side issue to the needing-to-invoke map (since it's lazily loaded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` used to work as you expected in Python 2.7, but now `map()` is lazy in Python 3.x, so you have to force it to work. Put the last line of your `level_up_all_players()` inside `list()`, like this:

```
list(map(lambda player: player.level_up(), lst_of_players))
```

**However**, this is not recommended. It's not usually a good practice to use `map()` just for the side effects (in your case, code is just adding 1 to player's level).
Normally, you work with the result that is produced using `map()`.

So, I really think you should use `for` loop for this kind of work, and it's easier to read than `map` with `lambda` for me and for many other people:

```
for player in lst_of_players:
    player.level_up()
```

**Update**

If you really want to achieve the same thing with just one line, you can do this:

```
for player in lst_of_players: player.level_up()
```

And I found a similar SO post that is about `map()` in Python. Please take a look at it: [link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623634/python-3-map-function-is-not-calling-up-function)

Answer (score 0):

`map` is lazy: the function isn't applied until you actually iterate over the `map` object.

Neither `map` nor a list comprehension, though, should be used solely for the side effect of the function being called on a value. Only use it if you want the return value of each function call. Just use a regular `for` loop instead:

```
for p in lst_of_players:
    p.level_up()
```