# Sorting a list of dot-separated numbers, like software versions

Tags: python

I have a list containing version strings, such as things:

```
versions_list = ["1.1.2", "1.0.0", "1.3.3", "1.0.12", "1.0.2"]
```

I would like to sort it, so the result would be something like this:

```
versions_list = ["1.0.0", "1.0.2", "1.0.12", "1.1.2", "1.3.3"]
```

The order of precedence for the digits should obviously be from left to right, and it should be descending. So `1.2.3` comes before `2.2.3` and `2.2.2` comes before `2.2.3`.

How do I do this in Python?

Comment: Related [How to compare "version-style" strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11887762)

Comment: You can shell out to GNU sort: `sort --version-sort`

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Split each version string to compare it as a list of integers:

```
versions_list.sort(key=lambda s: map(int, s.split('.')))
```

Gives, for your list:

```
['1.0.0', '1.0.2', '1.0.12', '1.1.2', '1.3.3']
```

In Python3 `map` no longer returns a `list`, So we need to [wrap it in a `list` call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-x).

```
versions_list.sort(key=lambda s: list(map(int, s.split('.'))))
```

The alternative to map here is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34835951/4099593) for more on list comprehensions.

```
versions_list.sort(key=lambda s: [int(u) for u in s.split('.')])
```

Comment: For the regular expression solution you would just replace the s with the expression that returns the group that you want.  
For example: lambda s: map(int, re.search(myre, s).groups[0].split('.'))

Comment: This is pure elegance.

Comment: Sort return None, but list is sorted.

Comment: That key function will not work in Python 3 because `map` returns an iterator in Python 3, not a list. But this will work in both versions: `key=lambda s: [int(u) for u in s.split('.')])`.

Comment: Recommend you assume the reader is using Python 3 and show python 2 as the exception, if that's even needed.

Comment: How does the `s:` part of `.sort()` work? 
(I'm confused about where the `s` comes from)

Comment: This does not make sense to me. This seems like magic. This works but does not seem obviously logical. Maybe this is because I do not use `map` or `lambda` or specify a `key` to the sort or sorted methods often. It is like each list element is split on the dot into a separate list and sorted. Wow!

Comment: it works only with numbers, but it doesn't work if the version has hyphens. In this case, if I have he string "0-40" in he version I get: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0-40'

Comment: This is the only version which works correctly. The others (natsort, and packaging.version) both sort the micro versions alphabetically, leading to incorrect sort order.

Answer (score 181):

#### Python 3.10+

Stdlib distutils was deprecated, and it was removed entirely in Python 3.12 [(ref)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/). Please refer to the [answer from Tobias Leupold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72188040/674039) for the best approach in current Python versions.

#### Python < 3.10

You can also use `distutils.version` module of standard library:

```
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
versions = ["1.1.2", "1.0.0", "1.3.3", "1.0.12", "1.0.2"]
versions.sort(key=StrictVersion)
```

Gives you:

```
['1.0.0', '1.0.2', '1.0.12', '1.1.2', '1.3.3']
```

It can also handle versions with pre-release tags, for example:

```
versions = ["1.1", "1.1b1", "1.1a1"]
versions.sort(key=StrictVersion)
```

Gives you:

```
["1.1a1", "1.1b1", "1.1"]
```

Documentation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.2/Lib/distutils/version.py#L101

Comment: Seems more pythonic then Eli's solution.

Comment: There's also distutils.version.LooseVersion which is a little more forgiving with version numbers that end in letters ['1.0b', '1.0.2-final'], etc. or whatnot - I prefer this version since StrictVersion seems to be more oriented towards Python distutils specific version strings, LooseVersion caters to a wider swath of potential version strings you'll see in the wild.

Comment: `StrictVersion` does not handle versions such as '9.20.00.0': invalid version number is returned. I'm wondering if, however, this is because the actual version is indicated as `u'9.20.00.0'` ...??? Maybe this needs to be decoded to UTF-8.

Comment: In case you need more freedom, you could use distutils.version.LooseVersion over StrictVersion. See http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/distutils.version.LooseVersion-class.html

Comment: Unfortunately, even `LooseVersion` doesn't work if you have `['0.1.0', 'latest']` like you might get back from a docker registry. For that, I use the [natsort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31425911/117471) answer on this page.

Comment: what is the diff between using `key=StrictVersion` to `key=LooseVersion`?

Comment: Note that `distutils` is getting deprecated, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0632/. It mentions using `packaging` instead (which is third-party).

Comment: @PeterLithammer: Yes, you can do `versions.sort(key=packaging.version.Version)`. Also see [PEP440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/).

Comment: @djvg Your code returns `None`. This one works: `import packaging;
versions = ["1.1.2", "1.0.0", "1.3.3", "1.0.12", "1.0.2"];
sorted(versions, key=packaging.version.Version)`

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś It is expected to return `None`, because it sorts in-place. See [sorting-basics](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sorting-basics).

Answer (score 30):

[natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) proposes "natural sorting"; wich works very intuitively (in Python 3)

```
from natsort import natsorted
versions = ["1.1.2", "1.0.0", "1.3.3", "1.0.12", "1.0.2"]
natsorted(versions)
```

gives

```
['1.0.0', '1.0.2', '1.0.12', '1.1.2', '1.3.3']
```

but it works as well on complete package names with version number:

```
versions = ['version-1.9', 'version-2.0', 'version-1.11', 'version-1.10']
natsorted(versions)
```

gives

```
['version-1.9', 'version-1.10', 'version-1.11', 'version-2.0']
```

Comment: how to implement this with list of dictionary ? i.e.
[{'env': 'REE', 'version': 'API-1.1.12'}, {'env': 'REE', 'version': 'API-1.2.0'}]
I want to implement sorting based on version key.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`packaging.version`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/version.html):

```
from packaging.version import Version
versions = ['3.1', '0.7.1', '3.4.1', '0.7.7', '0.7.2', '3.3', '3.4.0', '0.7',
            '0.7.5', '0.7.6', '3.0', '3.3.1', '0.7.3', '3.2', '0.7.4']
versions.sort(key=Version)
```

Result:

```
['0.7', '0.7.1', '0.7.2', '0.7.3', '0.7.4', '0.7.5', '0.7.6',
 '0.7.7', '3.0', '3.1', '3.2', '3.3', '3.3.1', '3.4.0', '3.4.1']
```

Comment: Unfortunately [v22.0](https://github.com/pypa/packaging/releases/tag/22.0) deprecated `LegacyVersion` so it now only supports strict versions strings (no arbitrary strings), but before that it was my ideal solution.

Comment: This also works fine with prereleases like

`['1.0.0', '1.0.2', '1.0.12', '1.1.2-beta.1', '1.1.2', '1.3.3']`

One cavat though: As per debian convention, the prerelease should be written as `~beta1`, in this case the sorting fails:

`['1.1.2~beta1', '1.0.0', '1.0.2', '1.0.12', '1.1.2', '1.3.3']`

Answer (score 0):

I also solved this question using Python, although my version does some extra things, here is my code:

```
def answer(l):
    list1 = [] # this is the list for the nested strings
    for x in l:
        list1.append(x.split("."))
    list2 = [] # this is the same list as list one except everything  is an integer in order for proper sorting
    for y in list1:
        y = list(map(int, y))
        list2.append(y)
    list3 = sorted(list2) #this is the sorted list of of list 2
    FinalList = [] # this is the list that converts everything back to the way it was
    for a in list3:
        a = '.'.join(str(z) for z in a)
        FinalList.append(a)
    return FinalList
```

For versions there exist three things; Major, Minor, and the revision. What this does is that it organises it so that `'1'` will come before `'1.0'` which will come before `'1.0.0'`. Also, another plus, no need to import any libraries incase you don't have them, and it works with old versions of Python, this one was specifically meant for Version 2.7.6.  Anyway, here are a few examples:

```
Inputs:
    (string list) l = ["1.1.2", "1.0", "1.3.3", "1.0.12", "1.0.2"]
Output:
    (string list) ["1.0", "1.0.2", "1.0.12", "1.1.2", "1.3.3"]

Inputs:
    (string list) l = ["1.11", "2.0.0", "1.2", "2", "0.1", "1.2.1", "1.1.1", "2.0"]
Output:
    (string list) ["0.1", "1.1.1", "1.2", "1.2.1", "1.11", "2", "2.0", "2.0.0"]
```

If you have any questions, just comment on the answer!

Answer (score -2):

I have an answer to this question. Unlike other codes, my code is bit lengthy and has more time and space complexity.

The advantage of my code is that, this code just uses built in functions and could be of a great exercise to practice and master looping concept for the beginners.

```
x=["1.11.0","2.0.0","1.2.1","1.1.1",'1.2.0']                    #Driver List 
le=len(x)                                                       #Length of the given driver list
x2=[]                                                           #list to store the values of x after splitting 
mapping=[]                                                      #list to store the values after type converstion 
map1=[]                                                         #list to store the values after sorting 
final=[]                                                        #list to store the final value after concatenation 

#Loop for splitting the given values with respect to '.'

for i in x:
    y=i.split('.')
    x2.append(y)
#print(x2)

#Loop for mapping the string value to integer value. This conversion overcomes the issue we have 
#With simple sorting technique as given in the question, and helps us in sorting the versions in our desired format

for i in range(0,le,1):
    mapped=list(map(int,x2[i]))                                 # mapped is a return value for the map()
    mapping.append(mapped)                                      # mapped value which is now a int, is appended to mapping array
#print(mapping)

mapping.sort()                                                  #Sorts the elements present in mapping array


#Loop to re-convert all the sorted integer value to string type

for i in mapping:
    mapp=list(map(str,i))                                       # mapp is a return value for the map()
    map1.append(mapp)                                           # mapp is now a str, gets appended to map1 array
#print(mapp)

#Loop to cancatenate the str values in mapp array with the '.'
#This converts the individual str type values in mapp array to its original form, like those in DriverList 

for i in range(0,le,1):
    for j in range(0,1,1):
        h=map1[i][j]+"."+map1[i][j+1]+"."+map1[i][j+2]
        final.append(h)

#Loop to Print the desired answer

for i in final:
    print(i,end='  ')



#For Better understanding of this program, uncomment the print statements in line 13, 21, 31.
```

The Output for the above code will be like:

```
1.1.1  1.2.0  1.2.1  1.11.0  2.0.0
```

The above is the sorted versions given in the driver list. Hope my code is clear. Pls feel free to ask any doubts if you have in comment section