# Sorting chapters numbers, like 1.2.1 or 1.4.2.4

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sorting

I have the Model Chapter:

```
class Chapter(ndb.Model):
    tutKey = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Tutorial')
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    content = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    note = ndb.TextProperty()
    lvl = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    order = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    parentID = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Chapter')
    number = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

'number' is the base chapter (chap1 or chap 1.2 have number = 1). 'lvl' is for the depth of the chapter, for example, in chap1.1.1 the lvl is 3 and in chap1.1.1.1 lvl is 4. And the 'order' says the order of the chap, for example, in chap1.2 'order' is 2 and in chap2.2 'order' is also 2.

How can i sort the following chapters (for example)?

```
chapter 2
chapter 2.1
chapter 1.1.1
chapter 1.1
chapter 1
```

I have been thinking... should i create a StringProperty to save the chapter number like "1.2.1" and then split the string by '.' ?

---

EDIT: i created a ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True) the equivalent to ListProperty suggested by JBernardo. I'm able to store the data correctly, but I can't get a way to sort by the property. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574080/sorting-a-list-of-version-strings)

Comment: Save it as integers in a [`ListProperty`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ListProperty)

Comment: JBernardo, I'm trying your suggestion, do you know if it is possible to sort a query by a ListPorperty? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simpler way to solve my problem. 
I store the chapter in a different way. In `ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)`. This way i can sort it just my using:

```
newChaps = sorted(chaps, key=lambda obj: obj.version)
```

Where 'version' is the ndb.IntegerProperty.

Done.

Answer (score 3):

You can represent your chapters by tuples with the length of the maximum depths of sub-chapters. Not used sub-chapters are represented by zeros. Then following would be a representation of your chapters:

```
chapter 2      (2, 0, 0)
chapter 2.1    (2, 1, 0)
chapter 1.1.1  (1, 1, 1)
chapter 1.1    (1, 1, 0)
chapter 1      (1, 0, 0)
```

If these chapters are added to a list `l`, this list can be sorted by the lists' `sort` method.

```
chapters = [(2, 0, 0), (2, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0)]
chapters.sort()
print chapters
```

This gives:

```
[(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 0, 0), (2, 1, 0)]
```

**--- EDIT ---**

In case of dynamic comparison you can add a function to the `sort` method via the `key` option. This function is applied to every element of the list before sorting. In the following `expandChapter` expands a chapter `ch` to the depth `depth`. The `key` argument in `sort` accepts only one parameter. Therefore, the maximum depth `maxdepth` is calculated and `expandChapters` is given to `sort` via anonymous `lambda` function.

```
def expandChapter(ch, depth):
    ch = ch + (0,) * (depth - len(ch))
    return ch

print expandChapter((1,), 3)                                # prints (1, 0, 0)

chapters = [(2,), (2, 1,), (1, 1, 1,), (1, 1), (1,)]
maxdepth = max([len(i) for i in chapters])
print maxdepth                                              # prints 3

chapters.sort(key = lambda x: expandChapter(x, maxdepth))
print chapters
```

This gives the correct answer:

```
[(1,), (1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (2,), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: that only let me create 3 lvls... right? I want it to be dynamic. I want, if i want, to create a chapter with x lvls for example 1.1.1.1.1

Comment: Does this answer also applies to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14882833/1601970 
also, I don't understand this part:`ch = ch + (0,) * (depth - len(ch))`

Comment: I don't know about google-app-engine and `ListProperty`. It is a pure Python solution. `ch` is the original tuple and the `+` concatenates it with missing zeros. `(0,)*3` would produce `(0, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that sprung into my mind was to set up your routes to handle the chapters so to have something like:

```
1/1
1/2/1
```

etc