# Sorting a query by a ListProperty (NDB)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sorting

How do i sort a query by a ListProperty*?

the Model:

```
class Chapter(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    version = ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)
```

the 'version' stores values like:

```
1.1 -> [1,1]
1 -> [1]
2.1.1.1.1 -> [2,1,1,1,1]
1.2 -> [1,2]
2.1.2 -> [2,1,2]
```

I want to order it like:

```
1
1.1
1.2
2.1.1.1.1
2.1.2
```

*Im using NDB so, ListProperty = ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG I finally did it.

```
newChaps = sorted(chaps, key=lambda obj: obj.version)
```

So simple... and yet so much time to find it...

Answer (score 2):

That's not how listproperties work, unfortunately. For an ascending-order query, the value used will be the smallest in the list.
You'll have to store the values differently (as a string, for example) to do what you're asking.

Comment: And how would i sort with strings? I've rewrite my model so many times because of this... i just want to know a way

Comment: have version be a StringProperty, containing the values you want - '1.1', '1.2.1.1.1' etc.