# Issues during sorting a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list as follows:

```
original_list = [u'0.1.876',u'0.1.1102']
```

I need to sort this in reverse order, so I did the following:

```
sorted_list = sorted(original_list, reverse=True)
```

The output is `[u'0.1.876',u'0.1.1102']`, but i need the sorting to consider the last column of digits. So expected output is `[u'0.1.1102',u'0.1.876']`. Any suggestions on how i could get this done ?

Comment: do some research about sorting with a custom comparator

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574080/sorting-a-list-of-version-strings).

Comment: What about the other columns?Do they matter?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rfind` to index of the last `.`, cast to `int`:

```
original_list = [u'0.1.876',u'0.1.1102']

srt = sorted(original_list,key=lambda x: int(x[x.rfind(".")+1:]),reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [50]: original_list = [u'0.1.876',u'0.1.1102']

In [51]: sorted(original_list, reverse=True, key=lambda s: int(s.rsplit('.',1)[1]))
Out[51]: ['0.1.1102', '0.1.876']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by last column you mean the substring followed by the last dot, and that you are interested in numerical comparison, you can use the `key` parameter of `sorted` as follows:

```
original_list = [u'0.1.876',u'0.1.1102']
sorted(original_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[-1]), reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[u'0.1.1102', u'0.1.876']
```

Comment: `sorted(original_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[-1]))` in case of values 00001 etc

Comment: This has all the hallmarks of answering *exactly what was asked* without actually answering what is probably intended. If I were to guess, the questioner also wants `1.0.1` and `0.2.1` to be sorted ahead of `0.1.1102`.

Comment: Funny - I've seen answers get voted down for doing exactly what you are suggesting - guessing at the intent, rather than actually answering the question *as asked*.

Comment: Possibly, but I didn't downvote the answer, I just added some critique.