# How can i sort semantic versions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of software releases as versions. The software follows the semantic version specification, meaning there is a major version, a minor version and patch versions:

- 0.1
- 0.2
- 0.2.1
- 0.3
- ...
- 0.10
- 0.10.1

Is there a way in pandas to sort these versions so that 0.2 is bigger than 0.1 but smaller than 0.10?

Comment: I reopen question because OP want pandas solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pandas solution with `sorted`, [StrictVersion solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2574080/2901002) and assign to column:

```
print (df)
      ver
0     0.1
1     0.2
2    0.10
3   0.2.1
4     0.3
5  0.10.1

from distutils.version import StrictVersion

df['ver'] = sorted(df['ver'], key=StrictVersion)
print (df)
      ver
0     0.1
1     0.2
2   0.2.1
3     0.3
4    0.10
5  0.10.1
```

EDIT:

For sort index is possible use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
print (df)
        a  b
ver         
0.1     1  q
0.2     2  w
0.10    3  e
0.2.1   4  r
0.3     5  t
0.10.1  6  y

from distutils.version import StrictVersion

df = df.reindex(index=pd.Index(sorted(df.index, key=StrictVersion)))
print (df)
        a  b
0.1     1  q
0.2     2  w
0.2.1   4  r
0.3     5  t
0.10    3  e
0.10.1  6  y
```

Comment: so, it turns out i still have a problem with this: if there are other column(s), this does not also change the fields in the other column(s)- is there a way to accomplish something like sort_index with key=StrictVersion?

Comment: Give me some time.

Comment: Super, glad can help!

Comment: I need to use the index solution but it returns an error, because I have `Unknown` version too and it says: ValueError: invalid version number 'Unknown'

Comment: `StrictVersion` unfortunately doesn't follow the Semantic Versioning spec: For example, `1.0.4a3` is considered a valid version, but `0.2.0-rc.1+e1acc3.win64` isn't, even though it falls into Semantic Versioning spec.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the standard `distutils` for this!

```
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
versions = ['0.1', '0.10', '0.2.1', '0.2', '0.10.1']
versions.sort(key=StrictVersion)
```

Now it's sorted like this: `['0.1', '0.2', '0.2.1', '0.10', '0.10.1']`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2574230/7586861)

Comment: This is for list and they are asking for pandas series, this does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Those work fine if your values are unique, but here is the best solution that I've found for columns of semantic values that might have duplication.

```
import pandas as pd
from distutils.version import StrictVersion    

unique_sorted_versions = sorted(set(df['Version']), key=StrictVersion)

groups = [df[df['Version'].isin([version])]
          for version in unique_sorted_versions]

new_df = pd.concat(groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

I come across this problem too, after googling a lot (the first page I find is this SO question :D), I suppose my solution is worth to mention.

So for now there is two sort functions in pandas, `sort_values` and `sort_index`, neither of them have a `key` parameter for us to pass a custom sort function to it. See [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3942) github issue.

[jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44685497/632227) is very helpful and I'll build my solution based on that.

`df['ver'] = sorted(df['ver'], key=StrictVersion)` is useful only if the verion column is the single column in the DataFrame, otherwise we need to sort the other columns following the version column.

jezrael `reindex` the DataFrame, because the wanted index order can be obtained by the buitin `sorted` function, who does have a `key` parameter.

But, what if the version is not the index and I don't want to `set_index('ver')`?

We can use `apply` to map the original version string to a `StrictVersion` object, then `sort_values` will sort in the wanted order:

```
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
df['ver'] = df['ver'].apply(StrictVersion)
df.sort_values(by='ver')
```

Comment: If you need to sort with mutliple columns, you will have an error message because StrictVersion in not hashable. Here is the workaround:
`df["ver"] = df["ver"].apply(StrictVersion) ;
df["ver_tuple"] = df["ver"].map(lambda x: vars(x)['version']) ;
df.sort_values(by=['package', 'ver_tuple'], ascending=[True, False])`

Answer (score 0):

You can come up with something like that:

```
for module, versions in result.items():
    result[module] = sorted(
        versions, key=lambda x: mixutil.SemVersion(x.version), reverse=True
    )
```

Comment: can you provide a detailed example?