# Sorting a python list of semantic versions

Tags: python

I have a list of semantic code versions and I would like to sort it based on [semver](https://semver.org/). Here is an example where the default sort is incorrect:

```
['0.0.1', '0.0.2', '0.1.0', '0.10.0', '0.11.0', '0.12.0', '0.13.0', '0.13.1', '0.13.2', '0.14.0', '0.15.0', '0.16.0', '0.17.0', '0.18.0', '0.19.0', '0.2.0']
```

'0.2.0' should come before '0.10.0'. I know there are semantic libraries but didn't see any examples of how to sort with them, rather they check for validity of the semantic version.

Comment: Sorry, correct dup: [Sorting a list of dot-separated numbers, like software versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574080/sorting-a-list-of-dot-separated-numbers-like-software-versions)

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo for the link, that did not come up on the first few pages when I searched previously.  It does work as-is, thx!

Answer (score 5):

The following code should do the job:

```
a = ['0.0.1', '0.0.2', '0.1.0', '0.10.0', '0.11.0', '0.12.0', '0.13.0', '0.13.1', '0.13.2', '0.14.0', '0.15.0', '0.16.0', '0.17.0', '0.18.0', '0.19.0', '0.2.0']

a.sort(key = lambda x: [int(y) for y in x.split('.')])

print(a)
```

See the result:

```
['0.0.1', '0.0.2', '0.1.0', '0.2.0', '0.10.0', '0.11.0', '0.12.0', '0.13.0', '0.13.1', '0.13.2', '0.14.0', '0.15.0', '0.16.0', '0.17.0', '0.18.0', '0.19.0']
```

It works even if the list contains '0.12.0.1':

```
b = ['0.12.0.1', '0.0.1', '0.0.2', '0.1.0', '0.10.0', '0.11.0', '0.12.0', '0.13.0', '0.13.1', '0.13.2', '0.14.0', '0.15.0', '0.16.0', '0.17.0', '0.18.0', '0.19.0', '0.2.0']

b.sort(key = lambda x: [int(y) for y in x.split('.')])

print(b)
```

Here is the result:

```
['0.0.1', '0.0.2', '0.1.0', '0.2.0', '0.10.0', '0.11.0', '0.12.0', '0.12.0.1', '0.13.0', '0.13.1', '0.13.2', '0.14.0', '0.15.0', '0.16.0', '0.17.0', '0.18.0', '0.19.0']
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo, Thanks for pointing out the problem. It is now fixed.

Comment: Well now it's just a duplicate of the other answer (and its duplicate)... Why use `eval` here?

Comment: @Tomerikoo, You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples compare from left to right, so split each element into a tuple of ints and use that as a key:

```py
l = ['0.0.1', '0.0.2', '0.1.0', '0.10.0', '0.11.0', '0.12.0', '0.13.0', '0.13.1', '0.13.2', '0.14.0', '0.15.0', '0.16.0', '0.17.0', '0.18.0', '0.19.0', '0.2.0']
print(sorted(l, key=lambda version: tuple(int(n) for n in verion.split("."))))
# ['0.0.1', '0.0.2', '0.1.0', '0.2.0', '0.10.0', '0.11.0', '0.12.0', '0.13.0', '0.13.1', '0.13.2', '0.14.0', '0.15.0', '0.16.0', '0.17.0', '0.18.0', '0.19.0']
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2574090/6045800