# How can I add the corresponding elements of several lists of numbers?

Tags: python

I have some lists of numbers:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

How can I add these lists' elements, assuming that all of the lists that I'm using are the same length?

Here's the kind of output I'd like to get from doing this to the above lists.

```
[6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```

I know that I'll need a loop of some kind - but how can I do it elegantly?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this functional style code:

```
>>> map(sum, zip(*lists))
[6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```

The [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function matches elements with the same index.

```
>>> zip(*lists)
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7)]
```

Then [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) is applied to each tuple by using [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map).

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/0mmzI)

---

Note that in Python 3.x, `map` no longer returns a list. If you need the list, please see the following question:

- [Getting a map() to return a list in Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-1)

(You can just call `list`).

Comment: map returns a map object in python 3.x

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I'm assuming Python 2.x unless the OP specifies otherwise, but I've added a note about Python 3.x.

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> lis=[[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6,7]]

>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(*lis)]
[6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,3,4,5,6]
c = [3,4,5,6,7]
```

just do this:

```
[sum(n) for n in zip(*[a, b, c])]
```

Answer (score 6):

Using [numpy](https://numpy.org/):

```
>>> seq = np.array([
... [1,2,3,4,5],
... [2,3,4,5,6],
... [3,4,5,6,7]])
>>> np.sum(seq,axis=0)
array([ 6,  9, 12, 15, 18])
```

Comment: Unless the OP wants to continue using numpy, I am not sure that converting to and from numpy is the best way to go. Of course if more calculations need to be performed, numpy would be the way to go

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,3,4,5,6]
c = [3,4,5,6,7]

s = map(sum, zip(a,b,c))
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works for lists with various length too(nested only 1 time).

```
def sum_list_of_list_of_int(ll):
    l=[]
    for i in ll:  # "i" type is list
        for ii in range(len(i)):  # "ii" type is int
            if len(l)-1>=ii:
                l[ii]+=int(i[ii])
            else:
                l.append(int(i[ii]))
    return l
```