# Sum elements of list using condition on indexes

Tags: python, list, sum, element, conditional-statements

I have a list of length `L`, with some random values:

```
list1 = [3, 1, 1, 6, 8, 3, 7, 4, 8, 4]
```

and another list of the same length, with boolean values

```
list2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want to sum the values of `list1` where the corresponding element of
`list2` is `1`. (in this case 6+8+3)

is there an easy way to make it in Python?

Comment: What have you done? Did you make any attempts to solve the problem?.

Also possible Duplicate of [How can I add the corresponding elements of several lists of numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280536/how-can-i-add-the-corresponding-elements-of-several-lists-of-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> sum(compress(list1, list2))
17
```

**Explanation:** `compress()` takes two iterables, and yields elements from the first if the corresponding element of the second is truthy. `sum()` ... well, you can probably guess.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) with [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list1 = [3, 1, 1, 6, 8, 3, 7, 4, 8, 4]
>>> list2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> list(itertools.compress(list1, list2))
[6, 8, 3]
>>> sum(itertools.compress(list1, list2))
17
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a conditional comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> list1 = [3, 1, 1, 6, 8, 3, 7, 4, 8, 4]
>>> list2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

>>> sum(item for item, flag in zip(list1, list2) if flag)  
17
```

The `if flag` checks if the corresponding item is not-zero. If you want an explicit check for `1`:

```
>>> sum(item for item, flag in zip(list1, list2) if flag == 1)  
17
```