# How to subtract numbers from a set from another set in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to subtract the values inside of two lists.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,0,1,5]
c = a - b
#c should be = [0,2,2,-1]
```

The answer to [How can I add the corresponding elements of several lists of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280536/how-can-i-add-the-corresponding-elements-of-several-lists-of-numbers) is simular, but alot of the answers on it are only applicable to adding.

Please answer with how to subtract, if possible.

Comment: You mean `list`, `set`s are unordered in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add the corresponding elements of several lists of numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280536/how-can-i-add-the-corresponding-elements-of-several-lists-of-numbers).  It isn't exactly the same, but it is close enough to be closed as a dupe.

Comment: If much of your code is like this, you should try R. With `a` and `b` as vectors, `c <- a-b` would already do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) would be useful in your case:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [1,0,1,5]
>>> 
>>> import itertools as it
>>> 
>>> import operator as op
>>> 
>>> list(it.starmap(op.sub, zip(a,b)))
[0, 2, 2, -1]
```

OR:

```
>>> [item for item in it.starmap(op.sub, zip(a,b))]
[0, 2, 2, -1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
c = [a1 - b1 for (a1, b1) in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Most people use `numpy` for numerical operations (although p.magalhaes has the answer for "pure" python).

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,3,4])
b=np.array([1,0,1,5])
c = a - b
c
```

returns

```
array([ 0,  2,  2, -1])
```