# How can I get all of the average of values of each respective column of nested numpy arrays?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, error-handling

I am having trouble performing a column-wise operation for each column of a dim-2 numpy array. I am trying to adapt my case to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11280699/7345804), though my setup is different. My actual dataset is quite large and involves multiple resamplings, hence the syntax of the example below. If the code and explanation looks too long, consider skipping ahead to the header **Relevant**.

**Skippable (Only here to reproduce `zs` below)**

Consider an (`x_n, y_n`) dataset where `n = 0, 1, or 2`.

```
def get_xy(num, size=10):
    ## (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) where xi, yi are both arrays
    if num == 0:
        x = np.linspace(7, size+6, size)
        y = np.linspace(3, size+2, size)
    elif num == 1:
        x = np.linspace(5, size+4, size)
        y = np.linspace(2, size+1, size)
    elif num == 2:
        x = np.linspace(4, size+3, size)
        y = np.linspace(1, size, size)
    return x, y
```

Suppose we can calculate some metric `z_n` given arrays `x_n` and `y_n`.

```
def get_single_z(x, y, constant=2):
    deltas = [x[i] - y[i] for i in range(len(x)) if len(x) == len(y)]
    return constant * np.array(deltas)
```

Instead of calculating each `z_n` individually, we can calculate all `z_n`'s at once.

```
def get_all_z(constant=2):
    zs = []
    for num in range(3): ## 0, 1, 2
        xs, ys = get_xy(num)
        zs.append(get_single_z(xs, ys, constant))
    zs = np.array(zs)
    return zs
```

**Relevant:**

```
zs = get_all_z()
print(zs)
>> [[ 8.  8.  8.  8.  8.  8.  8.  8.  8.  8.]
    [ 6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.]
    [ 6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.  6.]]
```

For my purpose, I'd like to make a new list or array `vs` for which the value at each index is equal to the average of the values in the corresponding columns of `zs`. For this case, every element of `vs` would be identical (since each operation would be the average of [8, 6, 6]). But had the first element of the first sub-array been a 10 instead of an 8, then the first element of `vs` would be the average of [10, 6, 6].

**Unsuccessful Attempt:**

```
def get_avg_per_col(z):
    ## column ?= axis number
    return [np.mean(z, axis=i) for i in range(len(zs[0]))]

print(get_avg_per_col(zs))
Traceback (most recent call last):...
...line 50, in _count_reduce_items ## of numpy code, not my code
    items *= arr.shape[ax]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: So, tldr, you want to find the mean of each row, right?

Comment: Mean of each column, not row.

Comment: So you'd have 10 mean values? Not 3?

Comment: That's correct, my goal is to make a new list or array of the 10 means (one mean per column).

Comment: Gotcha. My answer should solve this. Let me know if there's any issues with it.

Comment: `rows.T = columns`. Nice, thank you!

Comment: Yep. You were almost there actually. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.mean` on the transposed `zs` to get the column wise mean.

```
In [49]: import numpy as np

In [53]: zs = np.array([[ 8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.],
    ...:  [ 6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.],
    ...:  [ 6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.]])

In [54]: np.mean(zs.T, axis=1)
Out[54]: 
array([ 6.66666667,  6.66666667,  6.66666667,  6.66666667,  6.66666667,
        6.66666667,  6.66666667,  6.66666667,  6.66666667,  6.66666667])
```

Comment: really nice one, and faster as always! Is a plus one