# Turn iterable of tuple into iterables of each element (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable, generator-expression

I have an iterable `delta` that generates tuple of two numbers `(dx, dy)`, and I want to compute the sum of each. The following doesn't work since `delta` is disposed after the first iteration.

```
x = sum(dx for dx, dy in delta)
y = sum(dy for dx, dy in delta)
```

Any idea? I'm thinking in the direction of somehow turning `delta` into two iterables of `dx` and `dy`, but have reached nothing so far.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280536/how-can-i-add-the-corresponding-elements-of-several-lists-of-numbers) question is related to yours, have a look at this one too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `zip()` and `map()` functions to apply the `sum()` on each column:

```
x, y = map(sum, zip(*delta))
```

Comment: The solution is very nice. But a quick question: will `zip(*delta)` fully consume `delta` and load the whole content into memory at once?

Comment: @Lingxi Not in Python-3 but in Python-2 `zip` returns a list. In Python-2 you should use `itertools.izip()`.

Comment: @Kasramvd Very good solution. @Lingx You could also create n independent iterators from a single iterable using `itertools.tee`

Comment: I think `zip()` doesn't consume it at once, but `*delta` does. No?

Comment: @Lingxi No I don't believe if it does. But still the way that python deals with your iterable depends on the type the functions you're using. In this case since built-in functions are embeded in C a built-in loop will consume your items one by one it's not like it loops multiple times on your iterable.

Comment: @Lingxi Which version of python you're using?

Comment: @Kasramvd I'm using CPython 3.6.4

Comment: @vaultah `print()` is not a reliable example because it's not supposed to loop over the arguments and its nature is completely different than a function like `zip()`.

Comment: @vaultah This doesn't proof that `it` is consumed by the `*` or by the `zip`. Nevertheless, I think the best way is to take a look at the source code.

Comment: @vaultah Also I should note that `*` will definitely consume the iterator at python level. The thing that I'm not sure about is the way it behaves with built-in functions.

Comment: Just throwing it out there (as a rather bizarre option.... but appears to work): `sum((Counter({'a': a, 'b': b}) for a, b in d), Counter())`

Comment: @JonClements What is `d` supposed to be? Isn't this a "Shlemiel The Painter"-based algorithm?

Comment: @Kasramvd in context I think it's obvious what it is... (plus I'm too lazy to type out delta on mobile)

Comment: @vaultah I really hope that it's not so, but It's more likely that it is. I couldn't find anything helpful (hopeful) in source. Neither in built-in source nor in parser.

Comment: @JonClements No problem I got it. Although it's terribly inefficient  but can be a good example to teach the summability of `Couner` objects lol.

Comment: Of course `a, b = reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]), d)` works with directly iterating and storing rather than relying on unpacking, but hardly the greatest readability...

Comment: For the technical details of how `*` unpacking is built into the function call syntax directly, there is a good answer from user2357112 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22365935/674039).  However, I'm not sure exactly how much of that is CPython implementation detail, and how much freedom other implementations might be given to do things differently.

Comment: @JonClements I actually quite like your `reduce()` solution.

Answer (score 3):

This ought to do it!

```
ysum = 0
xsum = 0

for dx, dy in delta:
    xsum += dx
    ysum += dy
```

The idea with a generator is that you can exhaust it once, so why not just do all of your math in one go?