# using map in python 3

Tags: python

Hi this code works in python 2.7 but not in python 3

```
import itertools
def product(a,b):
    return map(list, itertools.product(a, repeat=b)
print(sorted(product({0,1}, 3)))
```

it outputs

```
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

in python 2.7 but in python 3 it gives map object at 0x028DB2F0
does anyone know how to change this to work for python 3 so the output remains the same as in python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

Simply wrap it by a list this way:

```
import itertools

def product(a,b):
    return list(map(list, itertools.product(a, repeat=b))

print(sorted(product({0,1}, 3)))
```

Find more [Getting a map() to return a list in Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-1)

In two words in Python 3 map

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable,
>   yielding the results.

While in python 2.7 it

> Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the
>   results.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, the `map()` builtin returns an iterator rather than a list, behaving somewhat like the Python 2 `itertools.imap()` function.

If you need a list, you can simply pass that iterator to `list()`.  For example:

```
>>> x = map(lambda x: x + 1, [1, 2, 3])
>>> x
<map object at 0x7f8571319b90>
>>> list(x)
[2, 3, 4]
```