# python pdb lambda function global name error

Tags: python, lambda, pdb, nameerror

I was testing a fix using `pdb.set_trace()` to make sure it worked the way I expected before implementing it and kept getting a weird error.

```
(Pdb) test = [1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1]
(Pdb) max(range(len(test)),key=lambda i: test[i])
*** NameError: global name 'test' is not defined
```

So I moved to my localmachine to make sure I could reproduce as simply as possible before asking for help. In ipython I get the exact same behavior.

```
In [1]: test = [1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1]

In [2]: max(range(len(test)),key=lambda i: test[i])
Out[2]: 3

In [3]: import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
--Call--
> /Users/tristanmatthews/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.py(237)__call__()
-> def __call__(self, result=None):
(Pdb) test = [1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1]
(Pdb) max(range(len(test)),key=lambda i: test[i])
*** NameError: global name 'test' is not defined
```

But at the normal command line it works just fine:

```
tristan:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (x86_64)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:09) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test = [1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1]
>>> max(range(len(test)),key=lambda i: test[i])
3
>>> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
--Return--
> <stdin>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) test = [1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1]
(Pdb) max(range(len(test)),key=lambda i: test[i])
3
```

If anyone has any idea what is going on here I would REALLY love to know.

For the record the fix works fine in my code, just not in the debugger.

For reference my versions of python are:
Original error:

```
'2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15) \n[GCC 4.6.3]'
```

Local Machine both ipython and the command line are the same:

```
In [5]: sys.version
Out[5]: '2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (x86_64)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:09) \n[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)]'
>>> sys.version
'2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (x86_64)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:09) \n[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)]'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['NameError: global name is not defined' under pdb, for dictionary that does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151732/nameerror-global-name-is-not-defined-under-pdb-for-dictionary-that-does-exis)

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm this issue with Python 2.7. There is a [bug report for Python 3](https://bugs.python.org/issue21161) which suggests a [workaround](https://bugs.python.org/issue21161#msg215963): `interact` at the `pdb` prompt drops you into an interactive session which is populated with `globals()` *and* `locals()` and your `lambda` should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`pdb` isn't a full python shell, and intercepts a lot of things. But adding a `print` in front of it should work:

```
print max(range(len(test)),key=lambda i: test[i])
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work in this case, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40157383/396967).