# 'NameError: global name is not defined' under pdb, for dictionary that does exist

Tags: python, lambda, pdb, nameerror

I've encountered an issue re scopes in a `lambda` function.  I can successfully output foo to stdout but I get an error when using `max()` including a `lambda` - see simplified code below...

All in all, I am trying find the largest value for a nested key `budget` within an unknown number of first order keys.

```
(Pdb) foo = self.some_method()    # some_method() returns a dict, printed in the next step

(Pdb) pp foo

{'1': {'count': 1,
       'extra_data': {'activity-count': 1,
                             'budget': 0,
                             [...MORE KEY-VALUE PAIRS HERE...]
                             'version': 1},
       [...LOTS MORE KEY-VALUE PAIRS HERE...]
       'elements_total': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'result': 1, 'another_key': 2}),
       'extra_year_data': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10e05bd70>, {})}, 

 '2': {'count': 1,
       'extra_data': {'activity-count': 1,
                             'budget': 3,
                             [...MORE KEY-VALUE PAIRS HERE...]
                             'version': 1},
       [...LOTS MORE KEY-VALUE PAIRS HERE...]
       'elements_total': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'result': 1, 'another_key': 2}),
       'extra_year_data': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10e05bd70>, {})}}

(Pdb) max(foo, key=lambda x: foo[x]['extra_data']['budget'])
*** NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined
```

All in all, I am trying to use `max(foo, key=lambda x: foo[x]['extra_data']['budget'])` to find the largest value for a nested key `budget` within an unknown number of first order keys.

The expected result in this case could be `2` as the value for `foo['2']['extra_data']['budget'] = 3` vs. `foo['1']['extra_data']['budget'] = 0`.

Could the error be related to the fact that some of the (unrelated) keys have `defaultdict`s within them?

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you meant by environment, but that was run with pdb in terminal on python 2.7.6 on Mac 10.10.1 Yosemite.

Comment: No, sussed it out. All I needed was some more caffeine.

Comment: Why not `max(foo.values(), key=lambda x: x['extra_data']['budget'])`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You set a new *local* with `pdb`, but that is not visible to expressions using nested scopes in this debugger session. Any expression *in a nested scope* such as the `lambda` used for the `key` argument, using a name that is local to the current frame, would need to be a closure and will have this problem.

That's a limitation of how the debugger and Python compilation work; closures can only be created if the function that need to produce them was compiled in the same session. Since the function you are debugging was compiled without `foo` being a closure, it cannot be used by the `lambda` expression as such.

You can bind the local to the lambda (making it a local rather than a closure):

```
max(foo, key=lambda x, foo=foo: foo[x]['extra_data']['budget'])
```

See [What exactly is contained within a obj.__closure__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413946/what-exactly-is-contained-within-a-obj-closure) for details on how the Python compiler creates closures.

Comment: Thanks, I think that I understand this now. Does this mean that when I add this to my script, I don't need to bind the local to the lambda - i.e. I can just use `max(foo, key=lambda x: foo[x]['extra_data']['budget'])` ?

Comment: @user2761030: sorry, trying again. Yes, you can add this to your script, and because the Python compiler then sees the name `foo` in the `lambda` being used it'll create the closure in the parent scope. It'll then work. You just can't do this in `pdb`.

Answer (score 8):

There is a [bug report for Python 3](https://bugs.python.org/issue21161) (however this issue affects Python 2.7 as well as you found out) which suggests a [workaround](https://bugs.python.org/issue21161#msg215963) as an alternative to Martijn's solution: `interact` at the `pdb` prompt drops you into an interactive session which is populated with `globals()` *and* `locals()` and your `lambda` should work as expected.

Answer (score 7):

This is gonna mess with your global scope but it's a quick (dirty) workaround I use in this case when using python 2.7:

```
globals().update(locals())
```

Comment: Worked for me in python 3.6 as well