# 'x' is not defined when using list comprehensions in ipdb

Tags: python, pdb

```
ipdb> import ast
ipdb> [t.unparse() if isinstance(t, ast.AST) else t for t in tree]
*** NameError: name 'ast' is not defined
```

I was trying this code, but for some reason it clams that ast is not defined, even after importing. How to circumvent this?

Comment: try from ast import ast

Comment: Same problem, in fact this is due list generator having it's own scope https://bugs.python.org/msg215625, I find out an *ugly* solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible bug in pdb module in Python 3 when using list generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290314/possible-bug-in-pdb-module-in-python-3-when-using-list-generators)

Answer (score 2):

#### It gets better

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37624510/2089675)

Instead of doing it with globals, you could just make your `ipdb` session interactive by typing `interact` at the start of your session.

Now you can continue just the way you were and everything should work.

#### Better solution

Pull the module into the global scope

```
ipdb>  import ast
ipdb>  global ast # <-- This
ipdb>  [t.unparse() if isinstance(t, ast.AST) else t for t in tree]
```

#### Previous answer

You could also just create a global variable that refers to `AST`

```
ipdb>  import ast
ipdb>  AST=ast.AST
ipdb>  [t.unparse() if isinstance(t, AST) else t for t in tree]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I find out a way, but it's annoying.

First, this happens because list comprehension has it's own scope, so they don't work inside (i)pdb. For more info see this: https://bugs.python.org/msg215625

The solution is to use map + lambda to emulate list comprehension, I could get the same result by

```
!list(map((lambda t: t if type(t) is str else t.unparse()), tree))
```

The `!` is needed because `list` is a keyword in pdb

Comment: Another solution is to create a global variable that refers to `ast` and then use that global variable. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65801962/2089675)