# How to read an array of integers from single line of input in python3

Tags: python, arrays, list, input, python-3.2

I want to read an array of integers from single line of input in python3.
For example: Read this array to a variable/list

```
1 3 5 7 9
```

#### What I have tried

1. `arr = input.split(' ')` But this does not convert them to integers. It creates array of strings
2. `arr = input.split(' ')`

   `for i,val in enumerate(arr): arr[i] = int(val)`

2nd one is working for me. But I am looking for an elegant(Single line) solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Just adding, in Python 2.x you don't need the to call `list()`, since `map()` already returns a `list`, but in Python 3.x ["many processes that iterate over iterables return iterators themselves"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1303354/832621).

This input must be added with () i.e. parenthesis pairs to encounter the error. This works for both 3.x and 2.x Python

Comment: Thanks..It works and is faster solution than 2nd one proposed by me. You know, I tried `map(int, input.split(' ')` but It was returning map not list. Your answer solved this one too. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**: ***After using Python for almost 4 years, just stumbled back on this answer and realized that the accepted answer is a much better solution***.

Same can be achieved using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):
Here is example on [ideone](https://ideone.com/VbwjrG):

`arr = [int(i) for i in input().split()]`

If you are using Python 2, you should use `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: @crisron
`>>> a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]`
`1 2 3 4 5 6`
`>>> a`
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

[Click here for ideone example](https://ideone.com/VbwjrG)

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't work for me. On running this code, I am getting the prompt for input. I am giving input like this: `1 2 3 4 5`. It says `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @crisron are you using python2? if that is the case use the following:- `a = [int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]` that means use `raw_input()` in place if `input()`

Answer (score 2):

You can get a good reference from the following program

```
# The following command can take n number of inputs 
n,k=map(int, input().split(' '))
a=list(map(int,input().split(' ')))
count=0
for each in a:
    if each >= a[k-1] and each !=0:
        count+=1
print(count)
```

Comment: Code only answers are normally discouraged.  Do you think you could add a little description of how this works?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code that takes an input from user and reads it as array and not list.

```
from array import *
a = array('i',(int(i) for i in input('Enter Number:').split()))
print(type(a))
print(a)
```

IN addition , if you wish to convert it to a list:

```
b = a.tolist()
print(type(b))  
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just adding in :

1) If you want to take input on different lines use this:
    
n = int(input())
arr = [int(input()) for i in range(n)]

    for e.g 

    n = 5
    arr
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5

2) If you want input on the same line use `map`:

    As mentioned in above comment:
```

#### It returns a map iterator so we are type casting it to list

```
    n = int(input())
    arr = list(map(int, input().split()))


for e.g
n = 5
arr = [1 2 3 4 5]
```