# How to get N inputs from user in python

Tags: python, arrays

In my case I have to get `n` inputs from user as they entered

```
Please enter size of an array:
```

If the user enters 3 or whatever he likes, then the program should take 3 inputs from the user in a single line like this

```
1 2 3
```

And if he enters a value greater than 3, the program should warn him about the input he has given.

Is there any way to do this?

Input:

```
Enter size of an array: 5
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

And the main thing is that it should not ask the user each time to enter `5` as an input and also it should also check that the user entered the correct number of inputs.

Comment: __yes there are many ways to do this__

most of those ways will involve the following

`str.split`,`input`(or `raw_input`), `int`(or `float`), at least one `for loop` and some other stuff

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332801/how-to-read-an-array-of-integers-from-single-line-of-input-in-python3

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/how-can-i-get-a-list-as-input-from-the-user-in-python

Answer (score 6):

You can accept their input and convert it to an `int`

```
>>> size = int(input('Enter size of array: '))
Enter size of array: 3
```

Then use this value within the `range` function to iterate that many times. Doing so in a list comprehension you can repeatedly ask for input the same way.

```
>>> values = [int(input('Enter a value: ')) for _ in range(size)]
Enter a value: 3
Enter a value: 5
Enter a value: 7

>>> values
[3, 5, 7]
```

To do this in a more step-by-step manner you can use a `for` loop

```
values = []
for _ in range(size):
    values.append(int(input('Enter a value: ')))
```

If you just want them to enter a line of values, don't worry about asking how many there will be. You can use `split()` to tokenize the string on whitespace (or whatever delimiter you pass in), then convert each value to an `int`.

```
>>> values = [int(i) for i in input('Enter some values: ').split()]
Enter some values: 3 5 7 8
>>> values
[3, 5, 7, 8]
```

Comment: except he wants `my_input.split()[:size]` I think ... but yeah

Comment: @CoryKramer  if the user enter 5 as size of an array means it should not ask the user to enter 5 values again and again.