# Sort a list trough a function from user's input

Tags: python, list, input

I am trying to write a function which takes as argument a list of integers from the user input and sorts them.

I am getting some issues, because if I convert the integers to strings (I thought it could be the best way, because of the commas in the input) and append them in an empty list, I get an error.

Here the function:

```
def sort_integers(x):
    lst = []
    for i in x:
        lst.append(i)
        sorted_list = sorted(lst)
    print(sorted_list)
    
sort_integers(str(input("Enter some numbers: ")))
```

But if I enter 10, 9, 8 as integers, this is what I get as output:

```
[',', ',', '0', '1', '8', '9']
```

Expected output would be: `8,9,10`. I have tried to use `sort_integers(int(input("Enter some numbers: ")))` but I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10,9,8'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you studied `split` yet? If not, do so. Google "Python split string". You need to split the input string and then turn the resulting list of strings into a list of numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read an array of integers from single line of input in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332801/how-to-read-an-array-of-integers-from-single-line-of-input-in-python3)

Comment: Use input in a loop and append them as int in new list. Then sort() that list..

Comment: @TechieViN That doesn't solve the problem of reading multiple numbers separated with commas from a single line.

Comment: Try `sort_integers(map(int, input("...").split(',')))`, i.e. `split` the string by `,`, then `map` each substring to `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only interested in `digits` and when you use for loop you state the that for each symbol in my string add it to a list, `,` and   ( space ) is a symbol to Python.

Using `str.split()` on a string returns a list with the elements from the string, [have a read on it](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp). `split()` accepts an argument that you want to split your string on, in your case its `,`.

To achieve your result you can use the following:

```
def sort_integers(x):
    return sorted([x for x in x.split(',') if x.isdigit()])
```

I am returning the sorted list which is built from the string you pass to your function and taking only digits using `str.isdigit()` built-in method.

Also, you do not need to use `str(input()` because `input()` always returns a string no matter what you pass to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def sort_integers(x):
    x = x.split(',')
    sorted_list = sorted([int(i) for i in x])
    print(sorted_list)

sort_integers(str(input("Enter some numbers: ")))
```

**Or this (minimal change in your existing code)**

```
def sort_integers(x):
    x = x.split(',')
    lst = []
    for i in x:
        lst.append(int(i))
        sorted_list = sorted(lst)
    print(sorted_list)


sort_integers(str(input("Enter some numbers: ")))
```

**Output**:

```
 Enter some numbers: 10,9,8
 [8, 9, 10]
```