# The map function of python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

```
>>> dataset
[[1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5], [2, 5]]
>>> D=map(set,dataset)
>>> D
<map object at 0x0000000002ABF5F8>
```

When I input D into interactive window of python3.3,I supposed that it should appear:

`[set([1, 3, 4]), set([2, 3, 5]), set([1, 2, 3, 5]), set([2, 5])]`

Why a map object?

Comment: It return generator for 3+, Do `list(map(set, dataset))`

Comment: Read [Getting a map() to return a list in python 3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-1) I didn't read anywhere  But I observe the difference that in new Python version most in-built functions return generator instead of sequences (for efficiency purpose I suppose)

Comment: You can also use LCs `[set(i) for i in dataset]`

Comment: When noticing strange behaviour if using Py3, it is always worth to take a look at the function's documentation. There are many subtledifferences, making your life hard if you are used to Py2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the result of map is an object? Because in [documentation for python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) it is written that it yields the result, thus it is a generator.

You can read it by using

```
for i in D:
  print i
```

or as it was suggested by Grijesh

`list(D)` will convert it to list

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, map doesn't return a list, but a map object, an iterator. There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-1) about this.
If you need a list, you can easily convert it to a list:

```
D = list(map(set,dataset))
```

See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) about this.

By the way, it's a good practice to use lower case letters for variable names. Hope this helps!

Comment: Haven't seen yours when i wrote it. Sorry mate.