# How do I extract only floats from a list of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
output = []
stuff = ['candy', '1.3', '1.23']
floats = map(float, stuff[1:])
tuples = (stuff[0], floats)
output.append(tuples)
print(output)
```

instead of printing out `[('candy',[1.3,1.23])]` as intended, it prints out:

```
[('candy', <map object at 0x00000000038AD940>)]
```

I don't know whats wrong please show me the fix.

Comment: It printed out `[('candy',[1.3,1.23])]` as expected for me.

Comment: In both python2 and python3 your code works.

Comment: in py3 it shouls map object

Comment: do `floats = list(map(float, stuff[1:]))` instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-x

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you aren't converting the `map` to a list, try the following:

```
output = []
stuff = ['candy', '1.3', '1.23']
floats = map(float, stuff[1:])
tuples = (stuff[0], list(floats))
output.append(tuples)
print(output)
```

---

```
>>> output = []
>>> stuff = ['candy', '1.3', '1.23']
>>> floats = map(float, stuff[1:])
>>> tuples = (stuff[0], list(floats))
>>> output.append(tuples)
>>> print(output)
[('candy', [1.3, 1.23])]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python3 `map` returns a `map object`.

This is the way you can achieve what you want in Python3:

```
floats = list(map(float, stuff[1:]))
```

The output:

```
[('candy', [1.3, 1.23])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Python 2 eval of map:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun 10 2015, 19:42:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> map(float, ['1.1','1.2'])
[1.1, 1.2]
```

This is a Python3 lazy eval of map:

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jun 10 2015, 19:56:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> map(float, ['1.1','1.2'])
<map object at 0x103da3588>
```

What you are seeing is because you are running your code on Python 3. Wrap with `list` to fix.