# Mapping Values in a pandas Dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to filter out some data and seem to be running into some errors. 
Below this statement is a replica of the following code I have:

```
 url = "http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/2012-general-election-romney-vs-obama.csv"
 source = requests.get(url).text
 s = StringIO(source)
 election_data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(s, index_col=None).convert_objects(
        convert_dates="coerce", convert_numeric=True)
 election_data.head(n=3)
 last_day = max(election_data["Start Date"])
 filtered = election_data[((last_day-election_data['Start Date']).days <= 5)]
```

As you can see last_day is the max within the column election_data
I would like to filter out the data in which the difference between 
the max and x is less than or equal to 5 days
I have tried using for - loops, and various combinations of list comprehension.

```
 filtered = election_data[map(lambda x: (last_day - x).days <= 5, election_data["Start Date"]) ]
```

This line would normally work however, python3 gives me the following error:

```
 <map object at 0x10798a2b0>
```

Comment: for python 3 need add `list` - `filtered = election_data[list(map(lambda x: (last_day - x).days <= 5, election_data["Start Date"]))]`

Comment: see better explanation  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1303347/2901002)

Comment: That is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt has it almost right. The issue is

```
(last_day - election_date['Start Date']).days
```

which should instead be

```
(last_day - election_date['Start Date']).dt.days
```

`Series` objects do not have a `days` attribute, only `TimedeltaIndex` objects do. A fully working example is below.

```
data = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['Start Date', 'End Date', 'Entry Date/Time (ET)'])
data.loc[(data['Start Date'].max() - data['Start Date']).dt.days <= 5]
```

Note that I've used `Series.max` which is more performant than the built-in `max`. Also, `data.loc[mask]` is slightly faster than `data[mask]` since it is less-overloaded (has a more specialized use case).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to filter your data where any `Start Date` value that is `<=5` days away from the last day. This sounds like something pandas indexing could easily handle, using `.loc`.

If you want an entirely new DataFrame object with the filtered data:

```
election_data # your frame
last_day = max(election_data["Start Date"])
date = # Your date within 5 days of the last day
new_df = election_data.loc[(last_day-election_data["Start Date"]<=date)]
```

Or if you just want the `Start Date` column post-filtering:

```
last_day = max(election_data["Start Date"])
date = # Your date within 5 days of the last day
filtered_dates = election_data.loc[(last_day-election_data["Start Date"]<=date), "Start Date"]
```

Note that your `date` variable needs to be your date in the format required by `Start Date` (possibly YYYYmmdd format?). If you don't know what this variable should be, then just `print(last_day)` then count 5 days back.

Comment: `last_day-election_data["Start Date"]<=5` is not a valid comparison. The left side is a `Series` of `timedelta64[ns]` which cannot be compared against an integer.

Comment: Go note @IgorRaush. Totally forgot about the formatting of the dates. Updated the answer.