# one liner for converting the nth element of a list to a integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the first (or any) element of a list to integer form.

```
my_list = ['10','Sally']
```

I tried:

```
my_list = map(int, ['10','Sally'][0])
```

but the output of it is:

```
<map object at 0x7f3549b8aa58>
```

How can I fix my code to change it, so that in a one line expression `my_list` is equal to `[10,'Sally']`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a map() to return a list in Python 3.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-x)

Comment: `my_list[0] = int(my_list[0])`?

Comment: You are mapping `int` over `['10','Sally'][0]`, which is only `'10'`,by the way

Comment: Yes the result would be `[1, 0]` maybe not what you expected?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `map()` if you just want to change one element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in my_list]
# [10, 'Sally']
```

Or maybe (*Convert the nth element of a list to integer*):

```
n = 0
[int(v) if i == n else v for i, v in enumerate(my_list)]
# [10, 'Sally']
```

Comment: What if `i` is not a string (i.e., doesn't have an `isdigit()` method)?

Comment: @elethan Right. There are a lot of assumptions to be made here. A list can contain anything. Without a clearer context, this problem is difficult to touch.

Comment: why do you loop through if you only want to change one thing?

Comment: That is a good point actually. you can just do `my_list[0] = int(my_list[0])` this convert the 0th element to int in place.