# Lambda returns memory address

Tags: python, lambda

I feel like this problem is similar to [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-x)

```
return(lambda x: "Even" if number % 2 == 0 else "Odd")
```

Of cours I could solve the problem like this:

```
if number % 2 == 0:
    return("Even")
else: 
    return("Odd")
```

But I wanted to have a neat one-liner for this. Now I'm stuck, my code returns

```
at 0x7fb0378fb0d0>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Off-topic but I wouldn't really call this "neat", you are hurting your own maintenance (and slight performance) for no real benefit

Comment: `def f(x): return "Even" if x % 2 == 0 else "Odd"` is also a 1-liner, one which is much more readable. I don't see a plausible use-case for this particular lambda.

Comment: Agreed with comments above, generally don't use lambda unless you need an anonymous function (e.g. as a key for sorting)

Comment: So the way I posted the If/Else statement would be better?

Comment: Use the exact way of @JohnColeman, you still use `def` but then use ternary operator for a one liner

Comment: The if/else is much more readable. In most cases, you will read your code far more often than you write it; optimizing for readability will provide benefits again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda returns a function, so you get the address of the function.

Try this:

```
return ((lambda x: "Even" if x % 2 == 0 else "Odd")(2))
```

Here you execute the lambda function instead of just return the function itself.

You can assign the lambda function to a variable like this:

```
func = lambda x: "Even" if x % 2 == 0 else "Odd"
```

And then call to the function with the relevant parameter:

```
func(2)
```

Comment: Very usefull. Thanks. Why do I need to append the argument instead of integrating it into the lambda statement?

Comment: Consider x as the parameter that passed to the lambda, who is that x? you need to call to the lambda with that parameter, in this case it's 2.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use a lambda at all. Just do

```
return 'Even' if number % 2 == 0 else 'Odd'
```

or

```
return ('Even', 'Odd')[number % 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

lambda returns function

Try this

```
f = lambda (x :"Even" if x % 2 == 0 else "Odd")
print f(2)
```

Hope it helps !