# Looping over list of list division

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a list of lists, for example,

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [0,0,0]]
```

How do I output a list of lists, such that each element is assigned as a fraction of the sum of the sub-list.

In this example, the output should be:

```
[[1/6, 2/6, 3/6], [4/15, 5/15, 6/15], [7/24, 8/24, 9/24], [0,0,0]]
```

and should also check for division by zero, in which case, the entries are just zero.

Comment: Where did the denominators come from? Why are they specifically 6, 15, and 24?

Comment: @Rawing i think it is sum of the current list.

Comment: Sum of the sublist eg. 6=1+2+3, 15=4+5+6 ...

Comment: so you want output as 1/6 or 0.1666 ?

Comment: @Jay Parikh As decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `sum` of the sublist:

```
l =  [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
res = [map(lambda x: float(x)/sum(sl), sl) for sl in l]
```

Results with

> ```
> [[0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.5], 
>  [0.26666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.4], 
>  [0.2916666666666667, 0.3333333333333333, 0.375]]
> ```

PS,
For [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) [`map(...)` does not return a list, but a `map` object][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-x). To get a list:

```
res = [list(map(lambda x: float(x)/sum(sl), sl)) for sl in l]
```

PPS,
To avoid division by zero, you can replace the denominator with a conditional expression:  `sum(sl) if sum(sl) else 1`:

```
[list(map(lambda x: float(x)/(sum(sl) if sum(sl) else 1), sl)) for sl in l]
```

Comment: I am getting [<map object at 0x000000000BBC5320>, <map object at 0x000000000B7FE898>, <map object at 0x000000000B7FEA90>]. Can you have a direct ouput without the map?

Comment: @Mat.S apparently you are using python3. if you `list(map(...))` python will convert the map objects to lists.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing, how do you add a case that checks for division by zero and in those cases, the entries are just zero.

Answer (score 0):

Using a couple of comprehensions as:

#### Code:

```
[[float(z)/sum(x) for z in x] for x in y]
```

#### Test Code:

```
y = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

print([[float(z)/sum(x) for z in x] for x in y])
```

#### Results:

```
[   [0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.5], 
    [0.26666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.4], 
    [0.2916666666666667, 0.3333333333333333, 0.375]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done as follows, using list comprehension:

```
vals = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
denoms = [sum(entries) for entries in vals]
fracs = [[Fraction(entry, denom) for entry in entries] for entries, denom in zip(vals, denoms)]
floats = [[entry/denom for entry in entries] for entries, denom in zip(vals, denoms)]
```

Here I first calculate the denominators as the sum of the individual sublists, then I divide each element in the sublists with their respective denominators.

Also, I give you the output both in fractional (`fracs`) and decimal (`floats`) form. Pick whichever suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
list=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 
newList=[]
subList=[]
for el in list:
    for subEl in el:
        subList.append(subEl/sum(el))
    newList.append(subList)
    subList=[]
print(newList)
```

Output is:

> [[0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.5], [0.26666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.4], [0.2916666666666667, 0.3333333333333333, 0.375]]