# Python: casting map object to list makes map object empty?

Tags: python-3.x, casting

I have a map object that I want to print as a list but continue using as a map object afterwards. Actually I want to print the length so I cast to list but the issue also happens if I just print the contents as follows:

```
print("1",my_map)
print("1",list(my_map))
print("2",my_map)
print("2",list(my_map))
```

and this gives me the following outputs.

```
1 <map object at 0x7fd2962a75f8>
1 [(1000.0, 1.0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01)]
2 <map object at 0x7fd2962a75f8>
2 []
```

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it to continue using the map and its contents?

Comment: The one I'm using is 3.5.2

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A `map` object is a generator returned from calling the [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map) built-in function. It is intended to be iterated over (e.g. by passing it to `list()`) only once, after which it is consumed. Trying to iterate over it a second time will result in an empty sequence.

If you want to save the mapped values to reuse, you'll need to convert the `map` object to another sequence type, such as a `list`, and *save the result*. So change your:

```
my_map = map(...)
```

to

```
my_map = list(map(...))
```

After that, your code above should work as you expect.

Answer (score 9):

The reason is that the Python 3 `map` returns an *iterator* and listing the elements of an iterator "consumes" it and there's no way to "reset" it

```
my_map = map(str,range(5))

list(my_map)
# Out: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']

list(my_map)
# Out: []
```

If you want to preserve the map object you can use `itertools.tee` to create a copy of the iterator to be used later

```
from itertools import tee

my_map, my_map_iter = tee(map(str,range(5)))

list(my_map)
# Out: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']

list(my_map)
# Out: []

list(my_map_iter)
# Out: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue since I am using Python 3.7 version. Using `list(map(...))` worked. For lower python version using `map(...)` would work fine, but for higher versions, map returns an iterator pointing to a memory location. So `print(...)` statement will give the address rather than the items itself. To get the items try using `list(map(...))`

[image]