# Returning dictionary with list values in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have been tasked with updating some code from python 2.7 to python 3.6

Currently the code breaks with:

> TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Original code:

```
def test_create_page(self):
    """Ensure we can make a page"""

    response = DispatchTestHelpers.create_page(self.client)

    id = response.data['id']

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=response.data['id'])
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        self.fail('The page should exist in the database')

    print()
    print()
    print(response.data)
    print()
    print()
    # Check Data
    self.assertEqual(response.data['title'], 'Test Page')
    self.assertEqual(response.data['slug'], 'test-page')
    self.assertEqual(response.data['snippet'], 'This is a test snippet')
    self.assertEqual(response.data['content'][0]['type'], 'paragraph')
    self.assertEqual(response.data['content'][0]['data'], 'This is some paragraph text')
```

Original Output:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_create_page (dispatch.tests.test_api_pages.PagesTest)
Ensure we can make a page
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/icenine/code/ubyssey- 
dev3/dispatch/dispatch/tests/test_api_pages.py", line 67, in 
test_create_page
    self.assertEqual(response.data['content'][0]['type'], 'paragraph')
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

Thus far I have solved this by casting the map object to a list, however this returns an empty list. As far as I can tell the map object has not been touched in any way prior to being cast as a list, as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45018536/6448060.

The dictionary is returned from the following function:

```
@classmethod
def create_page(cls, client, title='Test Page', slug='test-page'):
    """Create dummy page"""

    url = reverse('api-pages-list')

    data = {
      'title': title,
      'slug': slug,
      'snippet': 'This is a test snippet',
      'content': [
        {
          'type': 'paragraph',
          'data': 'This is some paragraph text'
        }
      ]
    }

    return client.post(url, data, format='json')
```

Attempted Solution:

```
def test_create_page(self):
    """Ensure we can make a page"""
    response = DispatchTestHelpers.create_page(self.client)

    id = response.data['id']

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=response.data['id'])
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        self.fail('The page should exist in the database')

    data_list = list(response.data['content'])

    print()
    print(response.data)
    print()
    print(data_list)
    print()

    # Check Data
    self.assertEqual(response.data['title'], 'Test Page')
    self.assertEqual(response.data['slug'], 'test-page')
    self.assertEqual(response.data['snippet'], 'This is a test snippet')
    self.assertEqual(data_list[0]['type'], 'paragraph')
    self.assertEqual(data_list[0]['data'], 'This is some paragraph text')
```

Attempted Solution Output:

```
{'id': 1, 'slug': 'test-page', 'title': 'Test Page', 'featured_image': None, 'snippet': 'This is a test snippet', 'content': <map object at 0x7ff15f04e048>, 'published_at': None, 'is_published': False, 'published_version': None, 'current_version': 1, 'latest_version': 1, 'preview_id': '8720814f-a5e8-4892-b592-8cbb4d0d019f', 'template': OrderedDict([('id', 'default'), ('name', 'Default')]), 'template_data': {}, 'seo_keyword': None, 'seo_description': None}
[]
======================================================================
ERROR: test_create_page (dispatch.tests.test_api_pages.PagesTest) 
Ensure we can make a page
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/icenine/code/ubyssey- 
  dev3/dispatch/dispatch/tests/test_api_pages.py", line 77, in 
test_create_page
  self.assertEqual(data_list[0]['type'], 'paragraph')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As you can see in the first line, the 'content' key's value is a map object.

How can I access the list values from the returned dictionary?

Comment: Post more the the traceback so we can see which line failed.

Comment: for the original error or the attempted solution?

Comment: I added the traceback for the original error

Comment: The first one. Is it `response.data['content']` that is causing the problem? What is `response` anyway? Is it a `requests` module response? You could remove fluff in the example by doing `foo = response.data['content'][0]` instead of the other checks. `type(response.data)` would be interesting too. In the move to 3.x, you've also updated the tool chain. Whatever this `response` thing is may have changed what it does.

Comment: You spurred me to look into what the response type is, which includes a client object. This appears to be from the rest_framework which is located in my python 2.7 dist-packages! I think this may be the issue

Comment: Interesting. It all comes down to what `client.post(url, data, format='json')` returns. I don't know its API and a `map` object seems like a strange thing to return in a json object. But `list(map(...))` did build a list .... so you just aren't getting the data you expect.

Comment: I completely removed django from my python 2.7 dist-packages. Unfortunately the error persists.

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere. `django` is involved somehow. What is `response`? If its a `django` `StreamingHttpTResponse` , you have to use it a bit differently https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects

Comment: response is the response from using the  django.test.Client.post(...) function

Comment: `type(response)` would make it easier to find on the net!

Answer (score 0):

> `response.data['content'][0]['type']`

I suppose that `response.data['content']` is not a list, so an attempt to access its 0th element fails.

> `'content': <map object at 0x7ff15f04e048>,`

Look up the documentation for that `map` object; it's likely in the docs for the library you use to actually hit your URLs.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was in several module files associated with django. There were several functions that returned map types, one was for converting json data that returned with map. I wrapped the returned maps with a list like so

```
return list(map(<whatever is being mapped>))
```

And the problem for now appears to be solved.