# I use the function map() in python,and convert the results into a list,but the result is an empty list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printing, mapreduce

Why I am geting a wrong list when I use the function map() in python? here is my code,

When I use print() function to print list(r)

```
print(list(r))
```

my result is an empty list.

But When I write the code：

```
rList= list(r)
```

and then

```
print(rList)
```

my result is right.

here is my code:

```
def f(x):
    return x * x
r = map(f, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
rList= list(r)
print( list(r) )
print( rList)
```

here is my result:

```
[]
[1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]
```

and here is expected result

```
[1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]
[1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]
```

Comment: I feel like I've seen this question before...

Comment: @coldspeed Perhaps [stackoverflow.com/questions/45017937/python-casting-map-object-to-list-makes-map-object-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017937/python-casting-map-object-to-list-makes-map-object-empty)?

Comment: @RoadRunner that's a good one, ty.

Comment: @coldspeed No worries, I'll just make sure to close vote next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cast `r` (map object) to list it means that you run `f` function all over your list, and it will be finished. you can not use the result of `map` twice. like `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: Thaks a lot !!!! I understand !!!

Comment: @noobshane your welcome, please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers