# convert map to list , set , tuple in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, set, tuples

```
def addition(n):
    return n + n 
numbers = (1, 2, 3, 4)
result = map(addition, numbers)
print(list(result))
print(set(result))
print(tuple(result))
```

Output -
[2, 4, 6, 8]
set()
()

Why is only the print of list is executing correctly, the succeeding set and tuple are printing empty objects?

Comment: Because you've consumed the iterator into the list. The others get an empty iterator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: casting map object to list makes map object empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017937/python-casting-map-object-to-list-makes-map-object-empty)

Comment: The above posts have answer your question clearly. TO confirm the new understanding - you can add/modify this line:  `result = list(map(addition, numbers))` to see what's the difference

Answer (score 2):

I think that once you use the map object once, you cannot reuse it. I ran my own tests on IDLE, and I found that if you change the code so that `print(set(result))` comes first, this is the output:

```
{8, 2, 4, 6}
[]
()
```