# How can I solve "'NoneType' object is not callable" in Python 3 after using list()

Tags: python, nonetype

I'm new in Python 3 but using Python 2 to learn, and I have a problem of using     `None` in `map` function. I tried:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]; b = [4,5,6]; c = [7,8,9]
>>> map(None, a,b,c)
<map object at 0x029F9E90>
```

Then I found in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-x) and tried again:

```
list(map(None, a,b,c))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#191>", line 1, in <module>
    list(map(None, a,b,c))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

How can I solve this? Please sb advise.

Comment: `map(func, items)` applies a func to a list of items, one at a time. You wouldn't use None as a func. None doesn't do anything.   The "fix" you found is for converting a working map call in Python 2 to a Python 3 compatible version. But your initial map call is flawed, so wrapping it in a list doesn't help.  You could say `map(str, [1, 2, 3])` in Python 2, and that would give you back `['1', '2', '3']` In your case, `map(str, a)`, since your **a** is a list, would give the same result.

Comment: @Gary02127 `map(None, ...)` has a well-defined meaning in Python 2.

Comment: @vaultah - Interesting! I stand corrected. :)