# TypeError: 'map' object is not reversible

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow

I spent my time almost 2 hrs to use the pre-trained model (tensorflow) from  [weights.npz](https://github.com/AnjieZheng/Tensorflow-Number-Plate-Recognition) for detecting license plate but I can't fix it. I got this error message, I've never seen before. so, how to fix it?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./detect.py", line 189, in
>   
>       pt1 = tuple(reversed(map(int, pt1))) TypeError: 'map' object is not reversible

Comment: This is clearly a python 2 module, the code for python 3 should be `pt1 = tuple(reversed(list(map(int, pt1))))`; `list`s  after-all are definitely reverseible

Answer (score 3):

In python3, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator, not list. You need to wrap the call to `map()` with the `list` constructor:

```
pt1 = tuple(reversed(list(map(int, pt1))))
```

See more: [Getting a map() to return a list in Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) instead

```
pt1 = tuple(int(x) for x in reversed(pt1))
```