# Retrieve Map() values, using Python 3.6.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I've looked at other examples (like this for example [Getting a map() to return a list in Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-x/24507069#24507069)) and I haven't been able to figure it out. I'm trying to turn a list like this (it's about a thousand lines but I'm making it short for here)

```
xyz = [' 0.35587716 -2.11974747 -3.69604539',
       ' 0.32428861 -2.15566737 -3.61313426',
       ' 0.35329223 -2.19372613 -3.75673156']
```

Into either an array or list of floats like this

```
b = [[0.35587716, -2.11974747, -3.69604539],
     [0.32428861, -2.15566737, -3.61313426],
     [0.35329223, -2.19372613, -3.75673156]]
```

I have tried the following

```
b = np.array(map(lambda x: map(int, x.split()), xyz))
b = [[int(y) for y in x.split()] for x in xyz]

with open("file.log") as f:
    lis=[map(int,line.split()) for line in f]
```

And all of these give me back something like:

```
<map object at 0x117a89390>
<map object at 0x117a89390>
<map object at 0x117a89390>
```

etc, etc.

But I don't know how to access the values in the map object. I'm using Python 3.6.0. I'm not sure what to do :(

Comment: I looked at other examples and none of them have worked so far.

Comment: If you're already using `numpy` I would suggest you simply transform you array of sting into an array of float and use the `reshape` or `resize` methods to get a matrix. Easier and faster.

Comment: @ddog Why do you use `int` when you need `float`? I just tried `map(lambda x: map(float, x.split()), xyz)` and it outputs `[[0.35587716, -2.11974747, -3.69604539], [0.32428861, -2.15566737, -3.61313426], [0.35329223, -2.19372613, -3.75673156]]` just fine.

Comment: @blhsing When I try `map(lambda x: map(float, x.split()), xyz)` I still get "<map at 0x117b43c88>". I'm not sure what the deal is :/

Comment: @ddog Try casting it to `list` then: `list(map(lambda x: map(float, x.split()), xyz))`

Comment: @blhsing that still returned <map at 0x117b43c88>.

Comment: @domochevski when i try to convert it to a float array I get an error like this "ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 0.35587716 -2.11974747 -3.69604539'"  -- I think it's because there are spaces.

Comment: @ddog Then just iterate over it. Try `for i in map(lambda x: map(float, x.split()), xyz): print(i)`

Comment: @blhsing it still returns the same thing :/

Comment: @ddog in python 3 the following gives you a 1D array: `a=np.array([float(x) for s in xyz for x in s.split()])` from here you only need to use `a.resize(3,3)` to get the matrix.

Comment: @domochevski It works! Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it. I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now :)