# cuda in python issue

Tags: python, cuda

I have written the code below in order to discover the number of threads and blocks and send them to `train_kernel` function.

```
rows = df.shape[0]
thread_ct = (gpu.WARP_SIZE, gpu.WARP_SIZE)
block_ct = map(lambda x: int(math.ceil(float(x) / thread_ct[0])),[rows,ndims])
train_kernel[block_ct, thread_ct](Xg, yg, syn0g, syn1g, iterations)
```

but after execution, I face the error below:

> griddim must be a sequence of integers

Comment: What led you to believe that passing a map object would work?

Comment: i'm not familiar with python.what's your recommendation to use instead?

Comment: use a construct similar to what you used for `thread_ct`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1303347/681865 you are using Python 3. Map produces an iterator, not a list

Answer (score 1):

Although you have not stated it, you are clearly running this code in Python 3.

The semantics of  `map` changed between Python 2 and Python 3. In Python 2 `map` returns a list. In Python 3 it returns an iterator. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-x).

To fix this you need to do something like:

```
block_ct = list(map(lambda x: int(math.ceil(float(x) / thread_ct[0])),[rows,ndims]))
```

Alternatively you could just use a list comprehension without the lambda expression and map call:

```
block_ct = [ int(math.ceil(float(x) / thread_ct[0])) for x in [rows,ndims] ]
```

Either will yield a list with the necessary elements which should work in the CUDA kernel launch call.