# Print returning memory address in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

When I'm trying to print matrix1, the output is the memory address of the object.

```
print("enter n for nxn matrix")
n = int(input())

matrix1 = []
matrix2 = []

#taking elements of first matrix

print("Enter elements of first matrix")
for i in range(0,n):

  #taking elements of first column

  print("Enter elements of ",i,"column, seperated by space")

  #raw_input().split() will split the string
  #'1 2 34'.split() will give ['1', '2', '34']
  #map will convert its elements into integers [1, 2, 34]

  matrix1.append(map(int,input().split()))

print("Matrix 1 is",matrix1)
print(matrix1)
```

Ouput recieved.

```
enter n for nxn matrix
2
Enter elements of first matrix
Enter elements of  0 column, seperated by space
2 3
Enter elements of  1 column, seperated by space
4 5
Matrix 1 is [<map object at 0x101834898>, <map object at 0x1032d2f60>]
```

Not sure why the memory address of the object is being printed. I'm using python3.

Comment: `map` in python 3 return `map` object. If you want to convert it into a `list` you should call `list` function on it.

Comment: how could I print the value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a map() to return a list in Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 0):

`map` returns itself (or perhaps it is better to say it returns an object of its type?) but you can still iterate through it:

```
j = [1, 2, 3, 4]
j = map(lambda x: x+1, j)
{x for x in j}
```

Gives:

```
{2, 3, 4, 5}
```