# Why do i get <map object at 0x0389DCD0> when using map

Tags: python, python-3.x

What i have understood so far from the map function is that it applies a given function to each item in an iterable and returns the list of the result.

```
def square(num):
    return num**2

list_num = [1,2,3,4]
```

considering the  above function and the list of numbers as an example.

if we: `list(map(square,list_num))` we will get as an output `[1,4,9,16]`.

now comes the part that i am not able to find a sensible explenation of, if i

`print(map(square,list_num))` i will get as an output `<map object at 0x038B0290>`.

My question is, Why am i getting the memory location and not a list when i use the `print()` function or when use `map(square,list_num)`.

Comment: Because `map` returns a map object, not a list: "Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from each of the iterables. Stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a map() to return a list in Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303347/getting-a-map-to-return-a-list-in-python-3-x)

Comment: i understand how to get a list of results from map and how to use it... i just needed a sensible explanation why it outputted memory location when using map alone or with the print function. But Thanks :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` doesn't return a list. It returns a `map` object that lazily produces results as needed:

```
print(type(map(int, [1])))
<class 'map'>
```

It also doesn't override the stringify method which would produce pretty-printed results. That may be because that would require forcing the entire list to be evaluated, and if that's acceptable in your program, you probably shouldn't be using `map` in the first place; unless you're debugging, in which case use of `list` is probably fine unless you're dealing with an infinite list.

If you want a full-element print out, explicitly force it by placing it in a list before printing as you saw, or use a strict list production method like a list comprehension.