# Unable to resolve TypeError: Object of type 'map' is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-3.6

Error while parsing map to string using json.dumps in python 3.6

```py
x = {'id_str': '639035115457388544', 'video': False, 'photo': False, 'link': True, 'hashtags': <map object at 0x7f1762ab9320>, 'coordinates': None, 'timestamp_ms': 1441218018000, 'text': 'Police suspected hit-and-run', 'user': {'id': 628694263, 'name': 'Beth LeBlanc', 'friends_count': 235, 'verified': False, 'followers_count': 654, 'created_at': 1341631106000, 'time_zone': None, 'statuses_count': 3966, 'protected': 3966}, 'mentions': [], 'screen_name': 'THBethLeBlanc', 'reply': None, 'tweet_type': 'Tweet', 'mentionedurl': None, 'possibly_sensitive': False, 'placename': '', 'sentiments': 'Undefined'}

print(json.dumps(x))
```

```sh
TypeError: Object of type 'map' is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: how did you generate the `x`? where did you assign value to `hashtags`?

Comment: using a method like below:
def process_tweets(doc):
    tweet = {'id_str': doc['id_str'], 'video': False, 'photo': False, 'link': False}
    if doc['entities'].get('media'):
        tweet['photo'] = True
    if doc.get('extended_entities'):
        tweet[doc['extended_entities']['media'][0]['type']] = True
        tweet['mediaurl'] = doc['extended_entities']['media'][0]['media_url']
    if doc['entities'].get('urls'):
        tweet['link'] = True
    tweet['hashtags'] = map(lambda x: x['text'], doc['entities']['hashtags'])
    tweet['coordinates'] = doc['coordinates']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you get value for `'hashtags'`, but this below example will help you to solve your question a little bit. Surround your map object with [list()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

```py
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> some_map_value = map([],[])
>>> some_map_value
<map object at 0x7f380a75a850>
>>> 
>>> x = {'hashtags': some_map_value}
>>> x
{'hashtags': <map object at 0x7f380a75a850>}
>>> 
>>> json.dumps(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type map is not JSON serializable
>>> 
>>> list(some_map_value)
[]
>>> x = {'hashtags': list(some_map_value)}  # surround your map object with list
>>> json.dumps(x)
'{"hashtags": []}'
```

For more information check this [Getting a map() to return a list in Python 3.x
Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1303347/6194097) question. If this is not you are lokking for, please put a comment to this answer.

Update: Just check your comment. Surround your `map(lambda x: x['text'],doc['entities']['hashtags'])` with [list()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) like `list(map(lambda x: x['text'],doc['entities']['hashtags']))`

```py
if doc['entities'].get('media'):
    tweet['photo'] = True
if doc.get('extended_entities'):
    tweet[doc['extended_entities']['media'][0]['type']] = True
    tweet['mediaurl'] = doc['extended_entities']['media'][0]['media_url']
if doc['entities'].get('urls'):
    tweet['link'] = True
    tweet['hashtags'] = list(map(lambda x: x['text'],doc['entities']['hashtags']))
    tweet['coordinates'] = doc['coordinates']
```

Comment: It worked! I missed the list around the map. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome and happy hear about it @Yash. If this helpful for you please select this answer as accepted one by clicking the correct button below the votes of this answer. Thank you too!

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your x where the hashtags key has no corresponding value. Here it is fixed:
https://repl.it/repls/SubtleLovableSystemadministrator